# Generic type to get enum keys as union string in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

Consider the following typescript enum:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };
```

If I want another type that is the unioned strings of the keys of that enum, I can do the following:

```
type MyEnumKeysAsStrings = keyof typeof MyEnum;  // "A" | "B" | "C"
```

This is very useful.

Now I want to create a generic type that operates universally on enums in this way, so that I can instead say:

```
type MyEnumKeysAsStrings = AnyEnumKeysAsStrings<MyEnum>;
```

I imagine the correct syntax for that would be:

```
type AnyEnumKeysAsStrings<TEnum> = keyof typeof TEnum; // TS Error: 'TEnum' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

But that generates a compile error: "'TEnum' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

This is unexpected and sad.  I can incompletely work around it the following way by dropping the typeof from the right side of the declaration of the generic, and adding it to the type parameter in the declaration of the specific type:

```
type AnyEnumAsUntypedKeys<TEnum> = keyof TEnum;
type MyEnumKeysAsStrings = AnyEnumAsUntypedKeys<typeof MyEnum>; // works, but not kind to consumer.  Ick.
```

I don't like this workaround though, because it means the consumer has to remember to do this icky specifying of typeof on the generic.

Is there any syntax that will allow me to specify the generic type as I initially want, to be kind to the consumer?

Comment: You're running into the type/value name space issue that everyone seems to hit at some point, and it's obnoxious to explain.  The short answer to your question will be something like "no, the consumer will need to use `typeof MyEnum` if they want to refer to the thing with keys `A`, `B`, and `C`."

Answer (score 144, accepted):

No, the consumer will need to use `typeof MyEnum` to refer to the object whose keys are `A`, `B`, and `C`.

---

**LONG EXPLANATION AHEAD, SOME OF WHICH YOU PROBABLY ALREADY KNOW**

As you are likely aware, TypeScript adds a static type system to JavaScript, and that type system gets [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when the code is transpiled.  The syntax of TypeScript is such that some expressions and statements refer to *values* that exist at runtime, while other expressions and statements refer to *types* that exist only at design/compile time.  Values *have* types, but they are not types themselves.  Importantly, there are some places in the code where the compiler will expect a value and interpret the expression it finds as a value if possible, and other places where the compiler will expect a type and interpret the expression it finds as a type if possible.

**The compiler does not care or get confused if it is possible for an expression to be interpreted as both a value and a type.**  It is perfectly happy, for instance, with the two flavors of `null` in the following code:

```
let maybeString: string | null = null;
```

The first instance of `null` is a type and the second is a value.  It also has no problem with

```
let Foo = {a: 0};
type Foo = {b: string};
```

where the first `Foo` is a named value and the second `Foo` is a named type.  Note that the type of the value `Foo` is `{a: number}`, while the type `Foo` is `{b: string}`.  They are not the same.

Even the `typeof` operator leads a double life.  *The expression `typeof x` always expects `x` to be a value*, but `typeof x` itself could be a value or type depending on the context:

```
let bar = {a: 0};
let TypeofBar = typeof bar; // the value "object"
type TypeofBar = typeof bar; // the type {a: number}
```

The line `let TypeofBar = typeof bar;` will make it through to the JavaScript, and it will use the [JavaScript typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) at runtime and produce a string.  But `type TypeofBar = typeof bar`; is erased, and it is using the [TypeScript type query operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) to examine the static type that TypeScript has assigned to the value named `bar`.

---

Now, most language constructs in TypeScript that introduce names create either a named value or a named type.  Here are some introductions of named values:

```
const value1 = 1;
let value2 = 2;
var value3 = 3;
function value4() {}
```

And here are some introductions of named types:

```
interface Type1 {}
type Type2 = string;
```

But there are a few declarations which create **both** a named value **and** a named type, and, like `Foo` above, **the type of the named value is not the named type**.  The big ones are `class` and `enum`:

```
class Class { public prop = 0; }
enum Enum { A, B }
```

Here, the *type* `Class` is the type of an *instance* of `Class`, while the *value* `Class` is the *constructor* object.  And `typeof Class` is not `Class`:

```
const instance = new Class();  // value instance has type (Class)
// type (Class) is essentially the same as {prop: number};

const ctor = Class; // value ctor has type (typeof Class)
// type (typeof Class) is essentially the same as new() => Class;
```

And, the *type* `Enum` is the type of an *element* of the enumeration; a union of the types of each element.  While the *value* `Enum` is an *object* whose keys are `A` and `B`, and whose properties are the elements of the enumeration.  And `typeof Enum` is not `Enum`:

```
const element = Math.random() < 0.5 ? Enum.A : Enum.B; 
// value element has type (Enum)
// type (Enum) is essentially the same as Enum.A | Enum.B
//  which is a subtype of (0 | 1)

const enumObject = Enum;
// value enumObject has type (typeof Enum)
// type (typeof Enum) is essentially the same as {A: Enum.A; B: Enum.B}
//  which is a subtype of {A:0, B:1}
```

---

Backing way way up to your question now.  You want to invent a type operator that works like this:

```
type KeysOfEnum = EnumKeysAsStrings<Enum>;  // "A" | "B"
```

where you put the *type* `Enum` in, and get the keys of the *object* `Enum` out.  But as you see above, **the type `Enum` is not the same as the object `Enum`**.  And unfortunately the type doesn't know anything about the value.  It is sort of like saying this:

```
type KeysOfEnum = EnumKeysAsString<0 | 1>; // "A" | "B"
```

Clearly if you write it like that, you'd see that there's nothing you could do to the type `0 | 1` which would produce the type `"A" | "B"`.  To make it work, you'd need to pass it a type that knows about the mapping.  And that type is `typeof Enum`...

```
type KeysOfEnum = EnumKeysAsStrings<typeof Enum>;
```

which is like

```
type KeysOfEnum = EnumKeysAsString<{A:0, B:1}>; // "A" | "B"
```

which *is* possible... if `type EnumKeysAsString<T> = keyof T`.

---

So you are stuck making the consumer specify `typeof Enum`.  Are there workarounds?  Well, you could maybe use something that does that a value, such as a function?

```
 function enumKeysAsString<TEnum>(theEnum: TEnum): keyof TEnum {
   // eliminate numeric keys
   const keys = Object.keys(theEnum).filter(x => 
     (+x)+"" !== x) as (keyof TEnum)[];
   // return some random key
   return keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)]; 
 }
```

Then you can call

```
 const someKey = enumKeysAsString(Enum);
```

and the type of `someKey` will be `"A" | "B"`.  Yeah but then to use it as *type* you'd have to query it:

```
 type KeysOfEnum = typeof someKey;
```

which forces you to use `typeof` again and is even more verbose than your solution, especially since you can't do this:

```
 type KeysOfEnum = typeof enumKeysAsString(Enum); // error
```

Blegh. Sorry.

---

To recap:

- This is not possible
- Types and values blah blah
- Still not possible
- Sorry

Comment: This is brilliant, thank  you.  Double thumbs up for the additional nuanced education.  This makes me think that typescript might benefit from some kind of preprocessor which could (at least in this case) allow the code to look simpler.  But that wouldn't be typescript itself.  Thanks.  For now, I think I will choose to just force the consumer to understand and use the "keyof typeof" construction.  And I'm glad to have this page to reference for why!

Comment: I have found the answer! See my answer below! I would suggest removing `THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE` now :D

Comment: @Akxe I don’t see how your answer addresses the question, which is specifically about the keys of the enum and not the values

Comment: @jcalz Well you should now, you granted me an idea and that idea actually works! :D

Comment: The specific question is “how can I write a type function that takes in the name of an enum and outputs the union of its keys, without requiring the user to write `typeof` before the name of the enum”.  The answer is “you cannot; the name of the enum as a type describes its values and not its keys”.  Your answer does not even seem to attempt to address this question.  `keyof typeof MyEnum` is the type you want, but there’s no way to turn this into something like  `type KeyofTypeof<E> = keyof typeof E` because `E` must be a type while `typeof` expects a value, not a type.

Comment: SUCH a great answer! Possibly the best answers I've seen on SO, and there have been thousands. Thank you for taking the time to explain the fundamentals so clearly.

Answer (score 27):

There is a solution that doesn't require to create new generic types.

If you declare an enum

```
enum Season { Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter };
```

To get to the type you only need to use the keywords `keyof` `typeof`

```
let seasonKey: keyof typeof Season;
```

Then the variable works as expected

```
seasonKey = "Autumn"; // is fine
// seasonKey = "AA" <= won't compile
```

Answer (score 25):

It actually is possible.

```ts
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

type ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys = { [key in MyEnum]: string };

const a: ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys = {
    "0": "Hello",
    "1": "world",
    "2": "!",
};

const b: ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys = {
    [MyEnum.A]: "Hello",
    [MyEnum.B]: "world",
    [MyEnum.C]: "!",
};

// Property '2' is missing in type '{ 0: string; 1: string; }' but required in type 'ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys'.
const c: ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys = {  //  Invalid! - Error here!
    [MyEnum.A]: "Hello",
    [MyEnum.B]: "world",
};

// Object literal may only specify known properties, and '6' does not exist in type 'ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys'.
const d: ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys = {
    [MyEnum.A]: "Hello",
    [MyEnum.B]: "world",
    [MyEnum.C]: "!",
    6: "!",  //  Invalid! - Error here!
};
```

[Playground Link](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3lAggGigIWwYSgF8BuAKDIBc4AHYKAeQCMArYAY0oHUBLSgCwBqAQwA2YYAGcGAMySR0kgNLA4kqAF4oaANoBrVVB4hYiZAF0AXFEmUATsYDmxcmXYB7ELajDrzNpy8AiLiUrLyEIoqapraZFAJUABEAAxJ1kkAEsCiou5JmPGJSQCM6ckA7u52ogAmBUUJSQBM5UkAhA2kFB5elFBMfqwc3HxCYhLScshRqupaKI1QOvARAHToVsnZufmFicuryGs4W0lVNfX7iStmkGv4Z52F3W6e3uxDAaPBE2HTCmUc1iaCgAHowQkAJIgABuYh4tXaS1u602GR2eQaB1Rx1OGQudS6rl63lqXxGQXGoSmEVmMQWCQh0LhCKRKKO93R2xyWOuCVx93xlWqRP5hzuEAeT2xiQAbBlnmRukA)

---

EDIT: Lifted limitation!

```ts
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

type enumValues = keyof typeof MyEnum;
type ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = { [key in enumValues]: string };

const a: ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = {
    A: "Hello",
    B: "world",
    C: "!",
};

// Property 'C' is missing in type '{ 0: string; 1: string; }' but required in type 'ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys'.
const c: ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = {  //  Invalid! - Error here!
    A: "Hello",
    B: "world",
};

// Object literal may only specify known properties, and '6' does not exist in type 'ObjectWithValuesOfEnumAsKeys'.
const d: ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = {
    A: "Hello",
    B: "world",
    C: "!",
    D: "!",  //  Invalid! - Error here!
};
```

[Playground Link](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3lAggGigIWwYSgF8BuAKDIBc4AHYKUSANQEMAbMYAZygF4oA1sDgB7AGZRqdcbETJyU+gHkARgCtgAY0oB1AJaUAFgGlhXJWKSR0XU3B780AbSFwoekA2SsO3ALoAXFBclABOHgDmxORkmiIgIVAsQaoa2vpGduaWyDZZfFAoZFAlGEEARAASwGxsIuWYxaU4FQDuIqFsACYNTSX4FQCEvaQUcQmUUJop6lq6BiZmFlYQeWYFaFAA9FslAJIgAG7sel2DfWVQVTV1vaW4bR3dIzHjiV0zafOZSznWtutHCUdvsjiczhd0BVqrV6o17i0ru1Oj14aUBldhmiSgARIYvMhAA)

---

- This work with `const enum` too!

Comment: This is useful, thanks.  But not a full answer to the question.  Lots of good stuff in this thread though.

Comment: @StephanG Oh I see now, you want a type to transform enum to list of values or keys to be used in key indexes. This is not possible... The reason is that there is no `enum` type nor can an enum extend other enum. Thus you can not create `type<T extends enum> = { [key in T]: any}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can just pass a `type` instead of a `value` and the compiler won't complain. This you achieve with `typeof` as you pointed out.
Will be just a bit less automatic:

```
type AnyEnumKeysAsStrings<TEnumType> = keyof TEnumType;
```

Which you can use as:

```
type MyEnumKeysAsStrings = AnyEnumKeysAsStrings<typeof MyEnum>;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the OP question correctly and Akxe answer: Here is a possible further simplification. Use the typescript type utility. Record<Keys, Type>

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

e.g.

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

type enumValues = keyof typeof MyEnum;
type ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = Record<enumValues, string>
const a: ObjectWithKeysOfEnumAsKeys = {
    A: "PropertyA",
    B: "PropertyB",
    C: "PropertyC",
};
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to use the above with iMyInterface<K> instead of string.