# How to add "newable" constraint for generic parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-constraints

I already know how to add "newable" (i.e. has constructor) constraint for function arguments (like argument for `foo` function below), but same techique doesn't apply to generic type parameters.

Why is that and how to fix it ?

[image]

```ts
type NoParameterCtor<T> = { new(): T }

function foo<T>(ctor: NoParameterCtor<T>) { }

interface Bar<T extends NoParameterCtor<T>> { }

class Zoo { }

foo(Zoo) 
// no compiler error

class Zar implements Bar<Zoo> { }
// Type 'Zoo' does not satisfy the constraint 'NoParameterCtor<Zoo>'
```

Comment: No ordinary `T` will satisfy the constraint `T extends NoParameterCtor<T>`, because you are requiring an instance of type `T` to also be a no-parameter constructor function that is capable of creating new instances of type `T`.  What were you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `T extends NoParameterCtor<T>` is a strange constraint on `T`.  What are you actually trying to do?  Remember that the type `Zoo` is not newable, so `Zoo extends NoParameterCtor<Zoo>` is false.  The *value* `Zoo` has type `typeof Zoo` and is newable, but `typeof Zoo extends NoParameterCtor<typeof Zoo>` is also false because `new Zoo()` does not produce a newable thing.  Do you just want `T` to be any newable thing?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, what I want is "`T` to be any newable thing", how should I write that constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `T extends NoParameterCtor<T>` is an unusual constraint that means "`T` is a constructor that makes new instances of itself".  Unless you are trying to describe self-replicating constructors, this is not what you mean.

If you just want `T` do be "anything newable", then you don't need to care about the instance type.  Assuming you're using TS3.0 or later you can use `unknown` to mean any type, although you can use also `any`.  So perhaps you want `Bar` to be

```
interface Bar<T extends NoParameterCtor<unknown>> { }
```

The following still won't work though:

```
class Zar implements Bar<Zoo> { } // error! 
// Zoo does not satisfy the constraint NoParameterCtor<unknown>
```

That's because the type `Zoo` is not newable; it's the instance type of the `Zoo` class.  I don't know if you're confused about [the difference between named values and named types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) in TypeScript, but you're in good company if so.  In short, `class Zoo {}` introduces a *type* named `Zoo`, which is the type of instances of the class, and a *value* named `Zoo`, which is the constructor of such instances.  And the type of the `Zoo` value is not the `Zoo` type.  To refer to the type of the `Zoo` constructor value, you need to use `typeof Foo` instead:

```
class Zar implements Bar<typeof Zoo> { } // okay
```

Also I assume you've stripped out the contents of `Bar`, `Zar` and `Zoo` because they're not relevant here.  But just to be clear, empty interfaces match just about everything because TypeScript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).  If `Bar` needs access to the instance type of `T`, then you can use the built-in library type alias [`InstanceType<>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1416-L1419) to get it:

```
interface Bar<T extends NoParameterCtor<unknown>> {
   theConstructor: T,
   theInstance: InstanceType<T>
}

class Zar implements Bar<typeof Zoo> { 
  theConstructor = Zoo; // the constructor
  theInstance = new Zoo(); // an instance
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!