# How to parse a Enum in a Generic function to return an array of the enum values?

Tags: typescript, enums

I need to build a function where I can send an enum:

```
enum myExample {
   value1,
   value2
}
```

and return an array like

```
[myExample.value1,myExample.value2] : myExample[]
```

[I did this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20myExample%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value2%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems%3CT%3E(numberEnum%3A%20T)%3A%20T%5B%5D%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20arrayWithEnumItems%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20item%20in%20numberEnum)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(isNaN(Number(item)))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arrayWithEnumItems.push(numberEnum%5Bitem%5D%20as%20any)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(numberEnum%5Bitem%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arrayWithEnumItems%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems(myExample)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.dir(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B0%2C1%5D), the  but the return type of the function is wrong `let x: (typeof myExample)[]`.

```
 enum myExample {
    value1,
    value2
}

function getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems<T>(numberEnum: T): T[]{
    let arrayWithEnumItems: T[] = [];
    for (let item in numberEnum) {
        if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
            arrayWithEnumItems.push(numberEnum[item] as any);
            console.log(numberEnum[item]);
        }
    }
    return arrayWithEnumItems;
}

let x = getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems(myExample);
console.dir(x); // [0,1]
```

I am using Typescript 2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely confusing the named *type* `myExample` with the named *value* `myExample`.  They are not the same, despite the same name.  The *type* `myExample` is the type of the enum values which are numbers.  The *value* `myExample` has type `typeof myExample`, a map from keys `value1` and `value2` to those `myExample` enum values.  That is, `typeof myExample` is something like `{example1: myExample.example1, example2: myExample.example2}`.

(For more of my ranting about the difference between named values and named types in TypeScript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218))

Therefore when you pass in the value `myExample` to `getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems()`, you are passing in `typeof myExample` and want `myExample[]` to come out.  The way to get from the former to the latter is to do a [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) from `T` (corresponding to `typeof myExample`) to `T[keyof T]` (meaning "the values of the properties of `T`").

Thus you should amend your types to the following:

```
function getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems<T>(numberEnum: T): T[keyof T][] {
  let arrayWithEnumItems: T[keyof T][] = [];
  for (let item in numberEnum) {
    if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
      arrayWithEnumItems.push(numberEnum[item]); // no type assertion here
      console.log(numberEnum[item]);
    }
  }
  return arrayWithEnumItems;
}
```

Note how I've removed your type assertion of `numberEnum[item]` to `any`.  The error you were suppressing:

```
// Argument of type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

(that's the error TS3.1 gives.  TS2.6 probably gives a different-looking but similar error)

was trying to tell you that you were trying to push a property value onto an array of key-value maps, which was an error.  Sometimes you need to assert to get things done, but this is not one of those times.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I have to much to learn about Typescript... Thank you for your explanation here and in your other link! Just a quick question. Is there a reason why the returned type is `(myExample)[]` and not `myExample[] ` ? (with the parentesis)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the  value type of the enum by using a type query:

```
enum myExample {
    value1,
    value2
}

function getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems<T>(numberEnum: T): T[keyof T][] {
    let arrayWithEnumItems: T[keyof T][] = [];
    for (let item in numberEnum) {
        if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
            arrayWithEnumItems.push(numberEnum[item]);
            console.log(numberEnum[item]);
        }
    }
    return arrayWithEnumItems;
}

let x = getArrayWithNumberBaseEnumItems(myExample);
console.dir(x); // [0,1]
```