# Force an Enum to have just numerical values (type checks for Enum)

Tags: typescript

I want to force a ***Generic*** to be a *numerical enum*. I mean the **Enum** type should have just numerical values. An example below:

```
export type TNumberEnum<Enum> = { [key in keyof Enum]: number };

enum sample {
    AA,
    BB,
    CC = 'cc'
}

class SampleClass<CustomEnum extends TNumberEnum<CustomEnum>> {

    constructor( private value: CustomEnum ){}
    public sampleFunctin(): CustomEnum {
        return this.value;
    }
}

let a = new SampleClass<sample>( sample.CC ); // It should fail, keyof sample has string value

// valueOf and toString maybe could they cause problems?
```

[See a demo here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqA5ArgWwEbBQCiAdrgDym4B8cAvHAN5wDaA1sInAJYlweIIAMzhUcAXQBccMvkJwAvgG4AsACh1wWXADOAQxxgANqkbq4FuAEErAGnOWAQo-trLcAMIf6cAOQBjf191BXV1fyM9HR04AGUDY2APSOjyDywdGAgcMThQGC0AExjMXAJiWTSMrJzZalozN0sHC38IEkyoLH8sqAAKODAobgA3PQK4MaMsYGl0zOzcgEpGUKaLMCw8I25-XQSTADEsEh7ePqW56sXtRvd3KGAYLCg+GAALbh0AOimZ1XWihCYTUJngeh8JGAAHc4gckikdOR9IYTNQBijEt8vHAlko4AB6AlwACS8B07wgWCMhTgQj03CMtn4nGE+1RqHeUV0MGGJAA5pM9NNgCCiUKRQB5ER6Ei0rKxXm8QU4PSIAhwNrU+XvTiavQZVBDCDbYA4HQAfiAA)

I pass to **SampleClass** a custom **Enum**, however, I want that ***Generic*** ***Enum*** to be a *numerical enum*. Is it possible?

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqA5ArgWwEbBQCiAdrgDym4B8cAvHAN5wDaA1sInAJYlweIIAMzhUcAXQBccMvkJwAvgG4AsACh1wWXADKAQxxgANqkbq4cAIKWANObgAhB3bUWAwm-pwARACshbAAm-kH+3uoK6uoAxkZ6AM7xugbGwG5xiZRwoDBagUmyBFC0Zq5w0RAk8TBQWNEw0AAUYFDcAG56uXAdRljA0kQAlEyRZWBYeEbc0XDxKSYAYlgk9byNgwNM9hZQwDBYUHwwABbc8QB0PX2qZaOj6ibwel4kwADuyYYm6Qnx5PpfYDURoA1LnDyDJRwAD00OyUCgDz2cDwL3en1SP0yoJMwJxwHOTkhMLhhERake5TRH3xWPiIPmBKJUNhcAgbD0iHUQA)?  There's a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855626/2887218) between the *value* `sample` and the *type* `sample`.

Comment: I didn't think that the Enum extends from a number directly. Removing `CC` from the Enum which is a `string`, the compilation passes and adding some member with a `string` value, the Enum doesn't satisfy the `number` type. Solved.

Comment: So, would my comment constitute an answer for you if I wrote it up?

Comment: @jcalz yes sir!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not support type checks for the `Enum` type. You could modify your class to iterate over the enum elements to create a new object. In JavaScript the `Enum` is basically turned into an object.

For example the enum of your example results in

```
(function (sample) {
    sample[sample["AA"] = 0] = "AA";
    sample[sample["BB"] = 1] = "BB";
    sample["CC"] = "cc";
})(sample || (sample = {}));
```

which if executed results in

```
{
  0:    "AA",
  "AA": 0,
  1:    "BB",
  "BB": 1,
  "cc": "CC",
  "CC": "cc"
}
```

However when iterating over the properies you might not always be able to identify which property was an enum key and which an enum value.

If you somehow solve this problem you could create a new "enum" using the following example code

```
const myEnum = {}
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    myEnum[i] = keys[i]
}
```

effectively enforcing all enum values to be numeric.