# Map array of object to another array with different object in typescript

Tags: typescript

If i have something like

```
array1: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

and an interface like

```
export interface MyObject { name: string; }
```

how can I map array1 to another array of type MyObject?

```
array2 : MyObject[];
array2 = array1.map(s => ...);
```

I thought about something like

```
array2 = array1.map<MyObject>(s => new MyObject(...));
```

Comment: That works only if there's a constructor *value* named `MyObject` that produces instances of *type* `MyObject`.  Since `MyObject` is just an interface you could make one via an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) like `{name: s}`.  Is this homework or something?  Just wondering how much help we should provide here.

Comment: Not homework, code improvement of an angular application I bought from a supplier (company)

Comment: Then `array1.map(s => ({name: s}))` should work for you. (edit: surrounded expression with parentheses since js interprets `s => {...}` incorrectly here)

Comment: No that doesn't, compiler says `void is not assignable to type`, but this here works apparently `map(s => ({name: s}))`

Comment: my edit didn't make it to you in time, oh well

Comment: How about you make a true answer, so I can accept that for others?

Comment: Okay, if you insist!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is usually where I digress into a [long lecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) about the difference between types and values in TypeScript, but here I'll try to make it short: since `MyObject` is only known to be a *type* and not a constructor *value*, you can't call `new MyObject()`.  Instead, if you want to make a value of type `MyObject`, you can just use a plain old object [of the right shape](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), such as via [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
const myObject: MyObject = {name: "Alice"}; // no error
```

So your `map` function can be the following:

```
const array2: MyObject[] = array1.map(s => ({name: s})); // no error
```

Simple, right?

Uh, well, please note as in the comments above that the parentheses around `{name: s}` are [necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals), because for better or worse, JavaScript parsers interpret arrow functions of the form `(x => {...})` as having a [block body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) where the stuff inside the curly braces are statements.  And when you interpret `name: s` as a *statement* it means that `name` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), and `s` is just a string [expression statement](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) with the [optional semicolon omitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).  Interpreted as a function body, `{name: s}` just evaluates `s` and doesn't return a defined value (it is `void`, which is essentially the same as `undefined`), which is why you get the following weird error if you leave out the parentheses:

```
let array2: MyObject[] = array1.map(s => { name: s }); // error!
// Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'MyObject[]'.
// at runtime, array2 will be [undefined, undefined] which is not what you wanted
```

JavaScript parsing is a bit tricky this way.  Adding the parentheses to make `s => (...)` fixes it.  Now the stuff after the arrow can only be interpreted as a [concise body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)... that is, a single expression.  And interpreting `({name: s})` as an expression yields the object literal that we wanted.

Yay, I avoided writing a book about types and values and somehow ended up writing a different book about expressions and statements.  Oh well.

Answer (score 10):

you can't call `MyObject` as constructor because it is `interface` and not `class`. So an option here you can just map `array1` properties as `MyObject` properties and after that change type to `MyObject[]` array with `as`

```
const array1: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];

export interface MyObject { name: string; }

let array2 : MyObject[];

array2 = array1.map(v => { return {name: v}; }) as MyObject[];
```

or another option, you can also create `MyObject` class which will implement `IMyObject` interface and you can call constructor. Here is an example

```
const array1: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];

export interface IMyObject { name: string; }

class MyObject implements IMyObject {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let array2 : IMyObject[];

array2 = array1.map(v => new MyObject(v)) as IMyObject[];
```