# Return enum from enum value lookup

Tags: typescript

I have an enum `Animals` and I am trying to create a function that takes a value and the entire enum object returns the value as an emum if it is valid.

```
enum Animals {
  WOLF = 'wolf',
  BADGER = 'badger',
  CAT = 'cat',
 }

const coerseEnum = <T> (s, E: T): T | undefined => {
  const keys = Object.keys(E);
  const values = keys.map(k => E[k as any]);
  const obj = lodash.zipObject(keys, values);
  const key = lodash.findKey(obj, item => item === s);
  if (!key) return undefined;
  return E[key];
};

const x: Animals | undefined = coerseEnum('cat', Animals);
console.log(x);
```

However it's not casting to `Animals` but `typeof Animals`.

Comment: Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) and let me know if you still need an answer here; I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Don't want to mess with your code, but it's spelled "coerce" :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum has a type for the item of an enum (`Animal`) but also a type for the object that holds the values at runtime. This object is also named `Animal`, but it is not of type `Animal` since it contains all the entries for the enum. If we are starting from the type of the enum container object (`typeof Animal`) to get back to the type of the enum we need to write `typeof Animal[keyof typeof Animal]`

In your case, `T` is inferred to `typeof Animal`, the enum container object since that is what you are passing to the function. TO get back to the enum type we need to do `T[keyof T]`

```
enum Animals {
  WOLF = 'wolf',
  BADGER = 'badger',
  CAT = 'cat',
}

const coerseEnum = <T> (s: string, E: T): T[keyof T] | undefined => {
  const keys = Object.keys(E);
  const values = keys.map(k => E[k as any]);
  const obj = lodash.zipObject(keys, values);
  const key = lodash.findKey(obj, item => item === s);
  if (!key) return undefined;
  return E[key];
};

const x: Animals | undefined = coerseEnum('cat', Animals);
console.log(x);
```

**Note**
We usually don't notice this, but when we use `Animal` in a type annotation it is the type of an enum item, when we use `Animal` as a value we are talking about the container object which is not of type `Animal`. Just wanted to make that clear in case the previous paragraph was not 100% clear