# Property 'runStaticMethod' is a static member of type 'DemoClass'

Tags: typescript, static

I am getting the following error when I build the following typescript code.

```
Property 'runStaticMethod' is a static member of type 'DemoClass'
```

Typescript Code:

```js
export class Main {
    constructor(private demo: DemoClass) { }
    public run() {
        this.demo.runStaticMethod();
    }
}

export class DemoClass {
    public static runStaticMethod() {
        console.log('run...');
    }
}

new Main(DemoClass).run();
```

I am getting the following `console` error when I build the above `typescript` code. But the `javascript` code is running as expected.

Console Error:

```
Chitty:tsc NatarajanG$ tsc
src/index.ts:5:19 - error TS2576: Property 'runStaticMethod' is a static member of type 'DemoClass'

5         this.demo.runStaticMethod();
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Chitty:tsc NatarajanG$
```

Comment: Your `demo` property is not of type `DemoClass`, it's of type `typeof DemoClass`.  Change it to that and it should work (although you might choose to refactor that to something more general... otherwise just have `Main` depend on the `DemoClass` constructor without having to pass it in).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) if you are confused by the difference between `DemoClass` the type and `DemoClass` the value.

Comment: Also note that, as written, the type `DemoClass` is empty (no non-static properties or methods), which is [muddling up the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  Add an instance property to `DemoClass` in your code above and you'll also get the error on `new Man(DemoClass)`, since `DemoClass` *should not be* of type `DemoClass` itself.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's a static property and you should access it in the way how TS requires it: `DemoClass.runStaticMethod()`, despite javascript supports `this.demo.runStaticMethod()`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

> Each instance accesses this value through prepending the name of the class. Similarly to prepending `this`. in front of instance accesses, here we prepend `Grid`. in front of static accesses.

Answer (score 0):

My tests show that adding an `interface` for `DemoClass` with a definition for `runStaticMethod` resolves errors, eg...

```js
export interface DemoClass {
    runStaticMethod(...args: any[]): any;
}
```

... And for easy copy/paste here's a starting point to customize further...

```js
export interface DemoClass {
    runStaticMethod(...args: any[]): any;
}


export class Main {
    constructor(private demo: DemoClass) { }
    public run() {
        this.demo.runStaticMethod();
    }
}


export class DemoClass {
    public static runStaticMethod() {
        console.log('run...');
    }
}


new Main(DemoClass).run();
```

---