# Typescript - expect type which extends class

Tags: typescript

I need to create a function which would expect any type of class which extends another specific class (type, not an instance)

```
Class A{}

foo(b: typeof 'extends A')

Class B extends A{}

Class C {}


foo(B) => working

foo(C) => not working
```

How can it be done?

Comment: You are correct, what I tried to do is call foo(typeof B), and then the signature of foo is just foo(b: typeof A) and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz I think you should to post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be confused about what types are.  In `foo(B)`, the `B` is not a type; it is a constructor value.  This confusion is pretty common, probably because [sometimes types and values can have the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218), such as when you declare a `class`.

Anyway, if your requirement is that `foo()` should accept anything which is a constructor of `A` instances, the following should work:

```
class A { a: string = "A" }

declare function foo(ctor: new (...args: any[]) => A): void;

class B extends A { b: string = "B" }

class C { c: string = "C" }

foo(A); // okay
foo(B); // okay
foo(C); // error
```

The type `new (...args: any[]) => A` means "any constructor which produces instances of type `A`".  Thus `foo(B)` works because `B` is a constructor that produces instances of type `B`, a [subtype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) of `A`.  Thus `B` does produce `A` instances, and `foo(B)` works.  But since the type `C` is not a subtype of `A`, `foo(C)` yields an error.

---

I don't know what you want to do inside the implementation of `foo()`.  If you want to actually use the passed-in constructor, then you probably should think about what the constructor arguments need to be, and limit `foo()` to only accept constructors supporting those arguments.  For example, if you expect `foo()` to call its constructor with no arguments, you probably should limit it:

```
class A { a: string = "A" }

class B extends A { b: string = "B" }

class C { c: string = "C" }

// D's constructor requires a string argument
class D extends A { constructor(private d: string) { super(); } }

// ctor must be a no-arg constructor
declare function foo(ctor: new () => A): void;

foo(A); // still okay
foo(B); // still okay
foo(C); // still error
foo(D); // error
```

---

Also note that having empty classes like `class E {}` is [not recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), even for example code, because the TypeScript type system based on [structures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and not [names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  Since `class A {}` and `class C {}` have the same (empty) structure, if I had kept those types the call `foo(C)` would not give an error.  When in doubt, add differing properties to types you intend to be treated differently by the compiler.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: `foo(ctor: new (...args: any[]) => A)` ...that helped a lot! Thank you!