# Use Mixins with union types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, mixins, unions

I have a simple system where I generate classes by inheriting them from separate base classes and then mixing in another class to each of them. Here is my mixin class:

```js
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

/**
 * Based on the Mixin idea explained here:
 * https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-2-mixin-classes
 *
 * @param base
 * @constructor
 */
export function EntityServices<TBase extends Constructor>(base: TBase) {
  return class extends base {
    private _components = {};

    public addComponent(component: Component) {
      throw new Error('Not implemented');
    }

    public removeComponent(component: Component) {
      throw new Error('Not implemented');
    }
  };
}
```

This mixin is used in another module to create few classes like so:

```js
class ContainerEntityBase extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {}
class ImageEntityBase extends Phaser.GameObjects.Image {}
class SpriteEntityBase extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {}
class TextEntityBase extends Phaser.GameObjects.Text {}

export const ContainerEntity = EntityServices(ContainerEntityBase);
export const ImageEntity = EntityServices(ImageEntityBase);
export const SpriteEntity = EntityServices(SpriteEntityBase);
export const TextEntity = EntityServices(TextEntityBase);

// Type definitions have to be exported separately so that they can be used as types elsewhere, not as values
// Same name with values (classes) does not matter since TS stores values and types into separate
// namespaces.
export type ContainerEntity = InstanceType<typeof ContainerEntity>;
export type ImageEntity = InstanceType<typeof ImageEntity>;
export type SpriteEntity = InstanceType<typeof SpriteEntity>;
export type TextEntity = InstanceType<typeof TextEntity>;
export type BlackbirdEntity = ContainerEntity | ImageEntity | SpriteEntity | TextEntity;
```

As you can see, I have exported both actual created classes and their types with one extra union type `BlackBirdEntity`. Sometimes I'll use variables which may be any of the generated types, since in these cases these instances are operated on by their common mixed in interface.

Next I have the following simple definition which uses the union type:

```js
import { Component } from '../core/Component';
import { BlackbirdEntity } from '../core/entities';

export interface IEntityDefinition {
  name: string;
  components: Component[];
  type: BlackbirdEntity;
}
```

And I use it like this to create an object which implements the said interface:

```js
import { SpriteEntity } from '../core/entities';
import { IEntityDefinition } from './EntityDefinition';

const clickableEntity: IEntityDefinition = {
  components: [],
  name: 'Clickable',
  type: SpriteEntity
};
```

However, this gives me the following error on the IDE with `SpriteEntity` highlighted:

```
TS2322: Type '{ new (...args: any[]): EntityServices<typeof SpriteEntityBase>.(Anonymous class); prototype: EntityServices<any>.(Anonymous class); } & typeof SpriteEntityBase' is not assignable to type 'BlackbirdEntity'.   Type '{ new (...args: any[]): EntityServices<typeof SpriteEntityBase>.(Anonymous class); prototype: EntityServices<any>.(Anonymous class); } & typeof SpriteEntityBase' is not assignable to type 'EntityServices<typeof TextEntityBase>.(Anonymous class) & TextEntityBase'.     Type '{ new (...args: any[]): EntityServices<typeof SpriteEntityBase>.(Anonymous class); prototype: EntityServices<any>.(Anonymous class); } & typeof SpriteEntityBase' is missing the following properties from type 'EntityServices<typeof TextEntityBase>.(Anonymous class)': _components, addComponent, removeComponent
```

**Why?** And how to fix this? The error seems to suggest that the `SpriteEntity` is missing properties which are in reality in `TextEntity`'s parent class. So is there any way to tell the compiler this kind of type should be ok, even if their parents' definition differs?

Comment: The *value* `SpriteEntity` does not have *type* `SpriteEntity`.  Either you mean `IEntityDefinition['type']` to be `Constructor<BlackbirdEntity>` or you mean put an *instance* of type `SpriteEntity` as the `type` property of `clickableEntity`.

Comment: Yeah, I basically mean to put an instance of the `SpriteEntity` as the `type` property of `clickableEntity`. How do I express that with TS type defs? Or how do I attach the _type_ `SpriteEntity` to the _value_ `SpriteEntity`?

Comment: To clarify, I want to set the _value_ `SpriteEntity` to the propery `type` of the `clickableEntity`. Rather than _type_ the property should rather be _entityClass_ etc. since I want it to refer into a class which is later instantiated. The `clickableEntity` object is a configuration object for a factory.

Comment: So you want to use `Constructor<BlackbirdEntity>` instead of `BlackbirdEntity` in your definition of `IEntityDefinition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `IEntityDefinition` wanted its `type` property to be an *instance* of `BlackbirdEntity`, not a *constructor* of one.  You might be confused because for a `class` the constructor *value* generally shares a name with the instance *type*, even though [they are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218).

Anyway, you've already got a `Constructor<T>` type alias sitting around, so let's use it:

```
export interface IEntityDefinition {
  name: string;
  components: Component[];
  type: Constructor<BlackbirdEntity>; // you want a constructor, not an instance here
}
```

This should make your `clickableEntity` variable initialization compile without errors.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Ahh, that definitely makes sense! For some reason I didn't get that I'd have to specify the type as the constructor and accidentally used an instance. Thank you!