# What's the difference between "constructor", "static" and regular interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor, interface, static

TypeScript has two string interfaces called `String` and `StringConstructor`.

Also, the TypeScript [language specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) provides this code example, in chapter 1, section 1.3:

```
interface JQuery {
  text(content: string);
}

interface JQueryStatic {
  get(url: string, callback: (data: string) => any);
  (query: string): JQuery;
}
```

What's the difference between the `JQuery`/`JQueryStatic` and the `String`/`StringConstructor` interfaces and do `Static` and `Constructor` interfaces related?

**Note:** yes I'm aware that the page is <s>~6-7 years old</s> outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to switch from `String` to [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) because there is a wrinkle with `String` I will mention later<sup>*</sup>.

---

An instance interface (like `RegExp` and `JQuery`) usually represents an object type where multiple different instances can exist.  An associated static interface (like `RegExpConstructor` and `JQueryStatic`) usually represents the type of object that *creates* or *returns* these instances; and often there is only one of these static objects in existence.  So there is just one `RegExpConstructor` object that can make many `RegExp` objects, and just one `JQueryStatic` object that can make many `JQuery` objects.

One common source of confusion in practice is [name collision between values and types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218).  The name of the single static object (e.g., `RegExp` or `jQuery`) tends to be the same as the name of the instance interface.  But the type of that static object is not the type of the instance interface.  So, the *value* named `RegExp` at runtime has the type `RegExpConstructor`, not `RegExp`.  And the *value* named `jQuery` at runtime has the type `JQueryStatic`, not `JQuery`.  This is confusing but is probably for the best, since it lets you say things at runtime like `x instanceof Y` and at compile time that the type of `x` is `Y`.

Anyway, if there is a property or method whose behavior depends on a particular instance, that usually sits on the instance interface.  If there is some property or method whose behavior does not depend on a particular instance, that usually sits on the static interface.

---

A constructor interface is a static interface that specifically allows you to use the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on it to make new instances.  In TypeScript this is represented similarly to a function call signature, but with the name `new`, like this:

```
type F = (x: string) => number[];
type C = new(x: string) => number[];
```

The type `F` represents a function which takes a `string` parameter and produces an array of `number`s, while the type `C` represents a *constructor* function which takes a `string` parameter and produces an array of `number`s:

```
declare const f: F;
declare const c: C;
const arr1 = f("hey"); // number[]
const oops1 = new f("hey"); // error, f is not newable
const arr2 = new c("hey"); // number[]
const oops2 = c("hey"); // error, c is not callable
```

Having a static interface that is also a constructor interface is common; all `class` static interfaces are constructor interfaces.   But not every static interface is a constructor interface.  The `JQueryStatic` interface is an example of one which is not.  To get a `JQuery` instance from a `JQueryStatic` object, you call it like a function (that's the what the `(query: string): JQuery;` signature means).

So that's the main difference between the `JQueryStatic`/`JQuery` pair and the `RegExpConstructor`/`RegExp` pair, and the end of the main answer to the question.

---

<sup>*</sup>Back to the `String` wrinkle.  The type named `String` specifically refers to an *object* constructed by calling the `new` operator on the `String` constructor.  There is also the type named `string` (with a lowercase 's') which refers to the [*primitive*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) data type.  Virtually all of the strings you deal with are such primitives of type `string`, whereas a `String` is a relatively uncommon [wrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript) which holds a `string` value.  A `string` and a `String` are mostly interchangeable:

```
const stringPrimitive = "hello"; // type is string
const stringObject = new String("hello"); // type is String
console.log(stringPrimitive+"!"); // "hello!"
console.log(stringObject+"!"); // "hello!"
console.log(stringPrimitive.charAt(4)); // "o"
console.log(stringObject.charAt(4)); // "o"
```

except when they're not interchangeable:

```
console.log(typeof stringPrimitive); // "string"
console.log(typeof stringObject); // "object"
console.log(stringPrimitive instanceof String); // false
console.log(stringObject instanceof String); // true
```

The situation gets even more muddled when you realize that the `StringConstructor` can also be called like a function and produces a *primitive* `string`:

```
console.log(typeof "hey"); // "string"
console.log(typeof new String("hey")); // "object"
console.log(typeof String("hey")); // "string"
```

So it's quite a mess.  The rule here is pretty much [always use `string`; never use `String`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-and-object).  And that's why I changed the code example away from `String` to the always-an-object `RegExp`, for which there is no primitive data type (`typeof /foo/ === "object"`) to get in the way.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and putting in the effort to answer this question, I appreciate it.