# How to define string literal union type from constants in Typescript

Tags: typescript, string-literals, typescript3.0, union-types

I know I can define string union types to restrict variables to one of the possible string values:

```
type MyType = 'first' | 'second'
let myVar:MyType = 'first'
```

I need to construct a type like that from constant strings, e.g:

```
const MY_CONSTANT = 'MY_CONSTANT'
const SOMETHING_ELSE = 'SOMETHING_ELSE'
type MyType = MY_CONSTANT | SOMETHING_ELSE
```

But for some reason it doesn't work; it says `MY_CONSTANT refers to a value, but it being used as a type here`.

Why does Typescript allow the first example, but doesn't allow the second case? I'm on Typescript 3.4.5

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is an [enum](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)...?

Comment: You want `type MyType = typeof MY_CONSTANT | typeof SOMETHING_ELSE`.  There's a big difference between types (which exist only at design time) and values (which exist at runtime)

Comment: I often throw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) at people when I sense confusion between types and values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder considered that, but I've got constant strings that are defined elsewhere that I want to use

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - Fair enough, then Titian's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

To get the type of a variable you need to use the `typeof` type operator:

```
const MY_CONSTANT = 'MY_CONSTANT' // must be const, no annotation. let or var will not work
const SOMETHING_ELSE = 'SOMETHING_ELSE' // must be const, no annotation. let or var will not work
type MyType = typeof MY_CONSTANT | typeof SOMETHING_ELSE
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoGEDyA5AygFQIIY4wC8MA5IqprgTmQFCiSxZpwCiOAEgJIYDiSdgBks7EuVYdufQSLEMoATwAOAU3hKcqjaWXqQAM3jJ02fIRgAfGPrVGYUzrwFDR7evQA2a2AA8ALk1tdQBuej8JACIomBgAeniYNQAnFJAUiOjKMxpCKKA)

**Note:**

Since there seems to be a lot of confusion when people use this. The `const` matters. If you use other types of declarations (`let` or `var`) the final type would be string. Only `const`  preserves string literal types.

**Note 2:**

For this solution to work you must **not** specify any type annotation on the `const`, and let the compiler infer the type of the constants (ex this will **not work** :`const MY_CONSTANT: string = 'MY_CONSTANT'`)

Comment: yup, that worked. though I still don't get why I can create some string inline like `'test'` and use it directly, but need a `typeof` keyword if it's a reference.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu 'test' is both a value and a type (a string literal type), by definition (just like a class is a value, the constructor, and a type, the instance type)

Comment: `typeof MY_CONSTANT` will check if it is a whatever `string`, not specifically the `MY_CONSTANT`

Comment: @knuhol not sure I understand what you mean here. `typeof MY_CONSTANT` will give you the type of the constant, whatever that is. If you defined it in such a way that the type of it is `string` it will continue to be a `string`

Comment: If someone can explain the down-votes on this answer I would be grateful. I stand by the answer, it still does what it is supposed to and is an answer to  the original question. If someone has issues with it let me know

Comment: @knuhol see the note about `const` I think this is why you were getting `string`

Comment: Titian - the problem with your solution is that ANY string is a valid MyType.

Comment: @JonasRosenqvist please read the comments and the notes. Please check the playground link associated. If you use **const** then the literal type is preserved and type checking works as you expect and not all strings are compatible. If you have a sample where this is not true I would like to see it. Sorry if I sound a bit mad, but this answer keeps getting downvotes for no reason and it's getting very annoying. Not sure what I can do to make it more clear **const** is required

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - you're right, I had made the mistake of declaring the constant as:
`const MY_CONSTANT:string = 'MY_CONSTANT'`
Specifying the type of constant made it accept any string. Sorry, you'll get my upvote!

Comment: @JonasRosenqvist That is important feedback, I'll add it in the notes for the next person reading it. Thank you.

Comment: Important Note: It doesn't work when defining your strings with template literals. Then the types are just `string`

Comment: @Andru not true, as long as your string are constants, the delimiter does not matter. If you use interpolation then yes, they will be strings in 4.0: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoGEDyA5AygFQIIY4wC8MABoqprgTmQFCiSxZpwCiOAEgJIYDiSdgBks7EuVYdufQSLEMoATwAOAU3hKcqjaWXqQAM3jJ02fIRgAfGPrVGYUzrwFDR7eo3DRHbZ7LcxKgwUPCJSMicZV3l2ABIAb0ozGkIAXzIYAHosmBksGB4CgCkAVVxHHAAlWU8AGzVYAA8ALk1tdQBueiaJACI+mGzctQAnUZBRnv7k6gscPqA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for pointing that out. I indeed used a delimiter. I'm wondering why Typescript can't infer that the entire value will also be a string.

Comment: The problem with this that `Pick<MyType, 'MY_CONSTANT'>` will raise an error since Pick will try to extract the String prototypes rather than the actual strings

Comment: Regarding `The const matters`; what about `let MY_CONSTANT: 'MY_CONSTANT'` (notice the colon)?

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer indeed and it includes crucial details on how to get this right. But it goes to show that bolting a proper type system onto a language that originally didn't have one (that is, creating TypeScript on top of JavaScript) can result in something ugly and overly complex.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use enum for this case. For example:

```
// Define enum.
enum myConstants {
  MY_CONSTANT = 'my_constant',
  SMTH_ELSE = 'smth_else'
}

// Use it in an interface for typechecking.
interface MyInterface {
  myProp: myConstants
}

// Example of correct object - no errors.
let a: MyInterface = {
  myProp: myConstants.MY_CONSTANT
}

// Incorrect value - TS reports an error.
let b: MyInterface = {
  myProp: 'John Doe'
}
```

[More about enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Enums cover the case quiet well:

```
export enum ITEM_TYPES {
    TYPE1 = 'text',
    TYPE2 = 'image'
}

export type IItemType = ITEM_TYPES.TYPE1 | ITEM_TYPES.TYPE2
```

And then in code ITEM_TYPES can be refered to for all kind of runtime comparisons:

```
if (type === ITEM_TYPES.TYPE1){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a post related to string literal union type.
https://medium.com/@m.fatihalaziz/string-literal-union-type-with-typeguard-in-typescript-dff4c9741b4a

what it cover:

- how to create a string literal union type
- how to pass string as the string literal
- how to use the type guard of typescript effectively

I hope it helps,
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you Fatih. Just read your article, it's very detailed and informative!

Comment: I'm so glad my post can help you, thanks!