# How to define string literal union type from an array obtained via "require"

Tags: typescript

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263200/how-to-define-string-literal-union-type-from-constants-in-typescript), but with a twist.
I want to create a string literal union type, but the values from the initial array come from a **package** (json data file), and are obtained through "require"

The most common scenario is like this :

```
const namesArr = ["John", "Lily", "Roy"] as const;
type Names = typeof namesArr[number]; // "John" | "Lily" | "Roy"
```

But my scenario is like this :

```
const namesArr = require('names-package');
type Names = typeof namesArr[number]; // "John" | "Lily" | "Roy"
```

My problem is that Typescript thinks that type "Names" is really "any".

```
const name:Names = "John"; //Visual studio code shows "name" as being of type "any".
```

I can see inside the package that the data comes from a basic Json file :
**index.json**

```
[
  "John",
  "Lily",
  "Roy"
]
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Not unless `names-package` exposes more specific types than `any[]`.

Comment: As the next-best thing, I've skipped the external package altogether and instead copy-pasted the data into a local array of strings : ```const allMyStrings = ["John", "Lily"]``` . Visual Studio code still shows type ```Names``` as ```string[]```  when I hover, it's irritating. I don't know if it's just an intellisense thing and if I can trust the end-result.

Comment: If you're willing to do that, copy the array into your own code, why not also add `as const` to get the more specific type?