# What is the type of a class (not the instances)?

Tags: typescript

When you write a class `A` in Typescript, the type `A` is not actually the type of what the identifier `A` refers to in Javascript. `A` is the type of the instances of `A`. So, what is the type of `A` ?

Take this example :

```
class A {}

const B: ? = A;

const a = new B();
```

If we were to type B explicitly, what should we write to make this code compile ?

Comment: This is not a joke: it's `typeof A`.

Comment: @jcalz Now that was straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for more details about the difference between types and values and the confusion people have when the same name is used for a type and for a value.  The type `typeof value` is always the type of a value named `value`.  So `let x = "hey"; type X = typeof x;` is the same as `type X = string`.  For class constructors, though, the compiler actually *reports* "`typeof A`".  You could also use a constructor signature like `{new(): A}`.