# How to know which type to use in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

### The Main Question

I seem to keep running into this in different forms in typescript. Sometimes a function, or some kind of object requires a specific interface, and I'm looking for a general set of steps to follow to figure out what those interfaces are.

### Example Code

I'm trying to write a function that will iterate over the various colors of a Material-UI theme. I'm having trouble even accessing an individual one once I start passing parameters to do the job.

#### Working as expected

```js
const printColor = () => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();
  const color = theme.palette.primary['main'];
  console.log(color);
};
printColor(); // prints #3f51b5 to the console
```

### The failing example

```js
const printColor = (key: string) => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();
  const color = theme.palette.primary[key];
  console.log(color);
};
printColor('main');
```

The error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PaletteColor'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PaletteColor'.
```

### Further Thoughts

It seems as though I need to be adding some kind of type for the parameter `key`? I've been hunting around to try to figure out what type that would be. Why does this work when I access it directly as a string, and not when I pass it as a parameter?

Is there some way that you quickly determine which type to use when you run into these sorts of type errors?

### Run The Code

As requested here's a link to play with the code yourself. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6rntqm

The code runs here, but only gives a warning. I think my tsconfig is just set to fail, but I'm trying to learn how to troubleshoot these things myself.

Comment: Can you try giving `key` the type `keyof typeof theme.palette.primary`?  Can you provide a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so that I can give a more targeted answer?

Comment: I'll give it a go. I had trouble creating one in jsfiddle... but i'll try there.

Comment: Added a code demo @jcalz. Thanks!

Comment: Also @jcalz, the `keyof typeof ...` solution you mentioned does in fact seem to work. I didn't know that you could dynamically define types based on objects. That's very cool. Is this something you do often when using a library from someone else where you might not know where the typedefs are exactly?

Answer (score 2):

So the "right" answer for this probably looks like

```
import { PaletteColor } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";
```

and then later

```
const noLongerFails = (key: keyof PaletteColor) => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();
  const color = theme.palette.primary[key];
  console.log(color);
};
```

Note that we want `key` to be one of the keys of `PaletteColor`, so we use the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) type operator to turn an object type into a union of its keys.

Tracking down the proper `PaletteColor` type and where it's exported is a bit obnoxious (maybe someone has a better solution than what I did), but it looks like this:

- hover over `theme.palette.primary` in your IDE and see what IntelliSense says about its type:

  [image: IntelliSense]

  In this case it says `(property) Palette.primary: PaletteColor`.  So if we're lucky, there's a type exported somewhere called `PaletteColor`.
- If you have the relevant `node_modules` info for material-ui installed locally you can search it for that type.  If not, you can always look at the source code and [search that](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/search?q=PaletteColor&type=Code).  Fortunately there is [one hit](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.9/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L50-L55) and you can see it is exported as an `interface` in `styles/createPalette.d.ts`.
- We import from there and it works!

---

If we couldn't find an appropriately exported type, we could instead start using TypeScript's type queries to tease the required type from the things we *can* import:

```
type MyPaletteColor = ReturnType<typeof createMuiTheme>["palette"]["primary"];
```

Let's do this step by step. Given a named value like `createMuiTheme`, we can ask TypeScript for its type by using the [`typeof` type query operator](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/moving-types#capturing-the-type-of-a-variable).  (Not to be confused with the *runtime* `typeof` operator.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for a long explanation of the difference between type names and value names)  So `typeof createMuiTheme` is a function type:

```
type CreateMuiThemeType = typeof createMuiTheme;
// type CreateMuiThemeType = (options?: ThemeOptions | undefined, ...args: object[]) => Theme;
```

Now that function returns a `Theme`.  To get ahold of that type (pretending we haven't already imported it) we can use the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility type:

```
type MyTheme = ReturnType<CreateMuiThemeType>;
// type MyTheme = Theme;
```

Finally, we know that the type we're looking for is the `primary` property of the `palette` property of `Theme`.  For this we can use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) using indexed access notation:

```
type MyPalette = MyTheme["palette"];
// type MyPalette = PaletteColor;

type MyPaletteColorAlso = MyPalette["primary"];
// type MyPaletteColorAlso = PaletteColor;
```

We can collapse those into a single line as in `MyPaletteColor` above.  And oncewe have our own definition of `MyPaletteColor` we can use it instead of `PaletteColor`:

```
const alsoWorks = (key: keyof MyPaletteColor) => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();
  const color = theme.palette.primary[key];
  console.log(color);
};
```

and this also works.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Stackblitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-knlwyi)

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. Thank you so much for taking the time. I was confused on the `typeof` thing as well. Now it's time to implement it :)