# TypeScript: Differentiate between Class and Instance of class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, I have a class that stores a collection of objects.

```
class Collection<T extends Model> extends Array<T> {
  options: CollectionOptions;

  constructor(options: CollectionOptions) {
    super();

    this.options = options;
  }

  add(model: T): T {
    this.push(model);
    return model;
  }
}
```

I also have a mechanism to create new collections:

```
function createCollection<T extends Model>(
  _ModelClass: T, options: CollectionOptions
): Collection<T> {
  const collection: Collection<T> = new Collection(options);

  return collection;
}
```

I have some very reusable, generic options and a very basic model class:

```
type CollectionOptions = {
  key: string
}

class Model {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Now when I create a concrete class to use this with:

```
class User extends Model {
  id: number = 0
}
```

If I instantiate my collection like so:

```
const model = createCollection(new User(), { key: 'id' });
```

Then this is allowable:

```
model.add(new User());
```

But if I send the User class instead of an instance:

```
const model = createCollection(User, { key: 'id' });
```

Then I get this error when I try to do `model.add(new User())`:

> Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof User'.
>     Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'User' but required in type 'typeof User'.ts(2345)

Is there a way that I can modify my `createCollection` function to make it clear that its return type is a collection of *instances*, not *classes*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_ModelClass` argument to `createCollection` is completely unused inside the JavaScript, right?  It looks as though its only purpose is to give the TypeScript compiler an inference site for the generic parameter `T`.  If so, maybe the "right" solution is to do away with that argument entirely:

```
function createCollection<T extends Model>(
    options: CollectionOptions
): Collection<T> {
    const collection: Collection<T> = new Collection(options);
    return collection;
}
```

and either have callers manually specify the type of the `T` parameter as, say, `User`:

```
const model = createCollection<User>({ key: 'id' }); // manually specified 
model.add(new User()); // okay
```

or have them assign the return value to an manually annotated variable of type, say, `Collection<User>` and have the compiler infer `T` as `User` contextually from the desired return type:

```
const model2: Collection<User> = createCollection({ key: 'id' });
model2.add(new User()); // okay
```

---

If you want to preserve the dummy `_ModelClass` argument and your intent is to pass in a class *constructor* instead of a class *instance*, then `createCollection()` has the wrong signature.  Class declarations like your `User` example introduce both a named *interface type* corresponding to the type of class instances, and a named *value* referring to the class constructor. And these are different, despite having the same name.  The constructor value named `User` is not itself of type `User`.

The type named `User` is sort of like `{id: number; [key: string]: any;}`; an object with a numeric `id` property and a bunch of other possible properties, while the type of the value `User` (that is, `typeof User`,) is sort of like `new () => User`; a [newable](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable) object that *produces* a value of type `User` when called with `new`.

If you care to read more about the distinction between types and values and how the same name can refer to a type and a value depending on context, you could look at [another lengthy monologue of mine on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript/50396312#50396312).

In any case, if your intent is to accept constructors and not instances, you should annotate the type of the `_ModelClass` parameter not as `T`, but as something like `new (...args: any) => T` which means "a newable constructor that takes some number of arguments we don't care about and produces a value of type `T`":

```
function createCollection<T extends Model>(
    _ModelClass: new (...args: any) => T,
    options: CollectionOptions
): Collection<T> {
    const collection: Collection<T> = new Collection(options);
    return collection;
}
```

Then your function will accept the `User` constructor:

```
const model = createCollection(User, { key: 'id' });
model.add(new User()); // okay
```

But complain about a `User` instance:

```
const modelBad = createCollection(new User(), { key: 'id' }); // error!
// Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any) => Model`
```

---

If for some reason you want the compiler to accept *either* an instance *or* a constructor as `_ModelClass`, you can annotate that parameter as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of the instance and the constructor types:

```
function createCollection<T extends Model>(
    _ModelClass: (new (...args: any) => T) | T,
    options: CollectionOptions
): Collection<T> {
    const collection: Collection<T> = new Collection(options);
    return collection;
}
```

And then it will work both ways:

```
const modelCtor = createCollection(User, { key: 'id' });
modelCtor.add(new User()); // okay

const modelInstance = createCollection(new User(), { key: 'id' }); // error!
modelInstance.add(new User()); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-inbWmwQ5nJDAkifHDdlj6ozufi+YQ5sS7cyKauYtS2KKr1hL3jyb4yBGHzyoxEBcZ5CncDx5GK2CvDQswvqixCZkqUJQMe8jRLsGpajq+qKmQxozIIL5msWybWqmUG2JmsIeqoPp+gGIG0MWZbhpWmaurWDaxHQ4REbQ3EtsRcbFgmX5kjY1FkTaAHYKUtFelAeYFkxNCiaxFZOlGnEGPWjZwLxIAmu2nbdr20BBCgfb4DAwAlKu65klu5E7pR4IHsqqFrLCly0IiawomYWqVqUQxhUu3BJPM+hNCQvh2Oivk0EBiTibUN53mle6Umer60pBH5ZdgLJ-pWslYLymSqS0YEigV34wQG-G5AhVaKh5KFoc+tBYVA2p6ga+FzHBtB5fGqpkFaMm7nJmbZnRSkMYWcwsWGmltTpek8XxVIkWsABCCzSRRH7rRxboUDm9H5oxuncQq7AlAAhHM3GzpASmZv6gx9XAtJmOg3DtrqyB7HAexzkpEaheF7CRboMWkL4aEAAaCLMlAmV2PZ9sEVkQPgACi6D9AaGE0I5m5TSd37uf4nXeaeuz+ciCEsOtMOhnDUV6CAsXxU0AA+UAJUl55EEVuAZTE94zT+3W5Ga9UMlytNPqVnLlZV9TVVcNzge+DXDc1-ytUhHVHha5MtL1-W4Uaxu7SJAV2XhznTZRGZRvNinKbdK0uyUGkRudXH6YZJtjcWACSNJ6Ljk3blrIfaRdCm5ktYdNo97AvTEMdxz8EDB+xqdZwZO0Y0AA)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much for this very detailed answer. Helped me understand this a lot!