# typeof const typescript becomes a value

Tags: typescript

Can't understand why if I do this :

```
export const SET_EXPENSE = 'SET_EXPENSE';
export interface SetExpenseAction {
      type: typeof SET_EXPENSE;
      expenses: Expense[];
}
```

when I create the interface I need to give the type only as SET_EXPENSE.
typeof(SET_EXPENSE) is string, so why it becomes a values here and limits the type only to that string?

Comment: There are two `typeof` operators; the JavaScript `typeof` which exists at runtime, and will produce the string `"string"` when you use it on `SET_EXPENSE`, and the TypeScript type query operator `typeof` which only exists in the type system and will produce the *type* of `SET_EXPENSE` as seen by the type system, which is the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `"SET_EXPENSE"`.  See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I still donn't get when typof is used as a value and where it use a type, and when it is used as a js operator.If you could provide another explantion I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

The inferred type of `SET_EXPENSE` is the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `'SET_EXPENSE'`. TypeScript won't even allow you to compare it to a different string;

```
if (SET_EXPENSE === "other string") {...}
```

Gets you this error:

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"SET_EXPENSE"' and '"other string"' have no overlap.
```

Now if you set the type yourself, to `string`. It will work as you expect.

```
export const SET_EXPENSE: string = 'SET_EXPENSE'
```

Comment: This is all true, but I'd just note that wile using `const SET_EXPENSE: string = ...` is valid, its subtly incorrect. The `SET_EXPENSE` variable cannot be any string, it can only be the specific string `"SET_EXPENSE"`. OP should not override the inferred literal type, instead if he really needs it to be `string`, he should declare it with `let` instead of `const`.

Comment: My question is why it behaves like that and the vatiable SET_EXPENSE cannot be something else

Comment: @crice You're absolutely right, I was just answering the question as it was asked. I think it was useful still.