# Typescript template class typeof

Tags: typescript, class, templates

I currently have a function that needs to accept a class type, instantiate the class and return the INSTANCE, of a template type. I am getting an error: `'ActorType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

```js
spawnActor<ActorType extends Actor>(actorClass: typeof ActorType): ActorType {
    let actorObject = new actorClass();
    actorObject.sayHello(); // specific to Actor
    return actorObject;
}
```

Currently I found that the declaration works if I make the parameter type not using the template, `actorClass: Actor` rather than `actorClass: ActorType`. However when the function is called I have to specify the template type explicitly as it can't be inferred from the class passed into the `actorClass` parameter.

```js
spawnActor<ActorType extends Actor>(actorClass: typeof Actor): ActorType {
    let actorObject = (new actorClass() as ActorType); // must cast to template type
    actorObject.sayHello(); // specific to Actor
    return actorObject;
}

let a = spawnActor<MyActorClass>(MyActorClass); // have to give template type for a to have correct type
//let a = spawnActor(MyActorClass); // ideally it would be inferred
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator doesn't get the constructor of a class in general; it gets the type of a *value* with a certain name.  The confusion you're having is that classes declared with `class Foo {}` create both a type named `Foo` (the instance type of the class) and a *value* named `Foo` (the constructor for the class), and then `typeof Foo` is the type of that value.  But with the generic type parameter `ActorType`, there is no value named `ActorType` for you to get the type with `typeof ActorType`... and even if there were such a value there'd be little chance it would turn out to be the constructor of `ActorType` instances.  The distinction between types and values is important and confusing and I've [talked at length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) about this before.

What you're really looking for is a ["`new`able" call signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable).  If your instance type is `T`, then a constructor of no arguments which produces an instance of `T` has type:

```
new() => T;
```

or equivalently:

```
{ new(): T }
```

If you use `new() => ActorType` instead of `typeof ActorType` you should be able to make this work.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after!