# How to get Enum value by providing its name as parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, enums

I was looking for a similar case in the SO resources but I couldn't find similar topic, so I'm posting my question here.

How can I get returned enum value, based on providing its type name as parameter?

i.e I'd pass as a parameter this "ResetPasswordUrl" and I would like to return this "//a[contains(@href, 'reset-password')]/@href" expression as a result

```
enum CustomXPathExpressions {
ResetPasswordUrl = "//a[contains(@href, 'reset-password')]/@href",
OtherExpression = "//div" }
 
public getCustomExpressionValue(option: CustomXPathExpressions ) {
 
return here
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getCustomExpressionValue()` really takes `"ResetPasswordUrl"` as its input, then `option` is not of type `CustomXPathExpressions`.

There's a bit of a confusing situation in TypeScript where there are named *types* (only exist at design time) and named *values* (that exist at runtime) and you can have a type named `Foo` and a value named `Foo` and they don't have to be related to each other.  When you write `enum Bar { k1="v1", k2="v2" }` you introduce a *value* named `Bar` which is the enum object with property keys `k1` and `k2` whose property values are `v1` and `v2`.  You also introduce a *type* named `Bar` which is the union of the types of the enum object's property values, like `"v1" | "v2"`.  I have [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) which goes into painstaking detail on this.

Anyway, the type `CustomXPathExpressions` is the type of the *property value* of the enum, not the type of the `property key`.  To get the type of the key, you need `keyof typeof CustomXPathExpressions`.  And that means you will be *returning* the enum value, which is type `CustomXPathExpression`.  So your function should look like:

```
function getCustomExpressionValue(
    option: keyof typeof CustomXPathExpressions
): CustomXPathExpressions {
    return CustomXPathExpressions[option];
}
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
console.log(getCustomExpressionValue("ResetPasswordUrl")); /* 
  //a[contains(@href, 'reset-password')]/@href  */
console.log(getCustomExpressionValue("OtherExpression")); /* //div */
console.log(getCustomExpressionValue("bad key")); /* error! */
// ------------------------------->  ~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"bad key"' is not assignable to parameter of 
// type '"ResetPasswordUrl" | "OtherExpression"'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwmDOAXA9hAGgBQIaIBYFEAPABwCdh54BLZEeKAbwFgAoKdqAJQuEW0oDuyUgBMAqqQA2UALxQARAHpFWANoBjWoixU6ACgACucgDMANFADk5eLwC0xLIOEjLASgC6io6flnWHFAA8njApERkFNS0sgrKIlQAbvKsAL6srCZgIOqINCBQAOa8cEioETbRIABqWJJgwHoBHMjEebQAXFAA1sAAnsgmUIh9xMCDsAgo6Nh4FVH58KxuXaXTmDgEJJWLjFDN7OSIYKQFa6gbc9sLtPCqre0gHgDcaRksmnTIksAAdJLIQp6YqIc4QeaUfK1eqNeTcWx8JzwISiCSSeRuNzPKCKABUOJUGi0On0PmA5isNnsjmconcXjJQyguMUrE+8G+fwBQJBYIhVWhDT08hCuDC-PyGKxOPx8SSzNZH1unP+gOBJSm5WukNogthACMsCIev0pdi8VAwqRhABCBWsZRQOzOl2ut3uj0ugB87AAfv6AwGHYooABBUiFSCgRBQCYjMZWeSG429PrySxQKj0EDIGNIqiFEBYfU-YbIKCOUhYCC8MKxobB4ajYCJ+G8fjIlxo+RQAA+ClF4u1VXTv1YQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot jcalz, for brilliant introduction to what really enum is in Typescript, I'll check it out :P

Answer (score 2):

`return option.valueOf();` would do the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot will check it out :P, hope this will work :P

Comment: That's a no-op, though.  `option` is itself a string, so `return option` also works.

Comment: Yep I've faced the same problem as You've described, I should probably convert the string to the Enum key @jcalz how could I achieve this :p?