# How do I a union type of string values from an enum?

Tags: typescript

I have an `enum` like this

```
enum A {
  Car = "car",
  Bike = "bike",
  Truck = "truck"
}
```

and I want to get a type that is `car | bike | truck`

I know that `keof typeof A` can give me `Car | Bike | Truck` but I need the values here as opposed to keys.

Comment: Don't you just want... `A`? That's the type that means any of the values of the enumeration.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I would probably just ditch enums and use `'car' | 'bike' | 'truck'` in the first place.

Comment: This has a thorough explanation of why it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript 
However, like the 2 guys above me, I also believe that what you're trying to achieve can be done without a union of values. Can you specify what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware what you're trying to do here isn't possible with enums, unfortunately.

If you don't *have* to make use `enum` you can work around this by using an object to hold the values of your type and use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (only if you're using TypeScript 3.4+) to create a type based on the keys and values which acts as an enum-like type.

Example:

```js
const A = {
  Car: "car",
  Bike: "bike",
  Truck: "truck",
} as const;

type A = typeof A[keyof typeof A];

const x: A = A.Bike; // A.Car, A.Bike, A.Truck
const y: A = "bike" // "car", "bike", "truck"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am not sure when I should use `enum` vs. a const object. I just need a way to reference some hardcoded string but I thought `enum` is good for that.

Comment: `enum` is a great way to handle values that can be one of a specific set of cases, whereas if you're just looking for a way to restrict a type to be a series of specific values and don't need a "pretty" way to refer to the values through keys I would look at just creating a union type as was suggested in a reply to your initial question.

e.g. `type A = "car" | "bike" | "truck"`

I would only implement my example if you needed to refer to the key at a later point in the code.