# Distribute typeof over a union of classes

Tags: typescript, class, constructor, union

Consider this example:

```js
class A {}
class B {}
type AB = A | B
// type ABT = typeof AB // this does not work, error "AB is used as a value here"
type ABT = typeof A | typeof B
```

Is it possible to distribute `typeof` over the union without repeating the members?

Comment: `typeof` doesn't mean "give me a constructor for this instance type"; it means "give me the type of this value".  There is a *value* named `A` that exists at runtime which is a constructor of instances of type `A`, and there is a *value* named `B` that exists at runtime which is a constructor of instances of type `B`.  So `typeof A` is the type of the `A` constructor and `typeof B` is the type of the `B` constructor.  There is no *value* named `AB` that exists, unless you also write something like `const AB = Math.random()<0.5 ? A : B;` so there is no `typeof AB`.  Why do you need this?

Comment: There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218)... I'm kind of inclined to close this as a duplicate of that, although that is specifically about enums and not classes.  Both enums and classes have the same feature that make this confusing though: they introduce a value and a type of the same name but different meanings.

Comment: I understand about the constructors and their types. I am passing them as function parameters to check other instances against them (with instanceof) and I was hoping to have a more concise type definition for these parameters. They have a common subclass, but I cannot just use typeof Subclass as parameter type - it is not polymorphic... What would also help is a polymorphic type of constructor that allows types of subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply wanting a constructor type, you can use this:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T
type ABT = Constructor<AB> // new (...args: unknown[]) => AB
```

You can use this with `instanceof` and it also allows subclasses:

```
const something = (Class: ABT, object: unknown) => {
  if (object instanceof Class) {
    object // type AB
  }
}

class C extends A {}
something(C, {})
```

However, if the class has static members, this is **not the same** as `typeof`:

```
class D {
  static x = 0
}
declare const typeofD: typeof D
declare const constructorD: Constructor<D>

new typeofD()
new constructorD()

typeofD.x
constructorD.x // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Constructor<D>'.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C+AoUkYCFGoC4E8AHAUzmwF45oAfaTFFAk6AYQHsA7CXAJwFdguNjwA8AFQB80Sh2IB3aAAoAdKrA8A5hABc0PhwDWHNnI4BtALoBKaVLGMipWJjHTWnbv0HCRziQ2APXGgINgBbYlwACwBLDg03RRZwKF1nMQAaaDYAIwArYkFdfSMTDhtyKQQUaGgYgDMlXILBOq5cMA5gYjZG5Iwbatra5sLggHpx6CYnelrUVDQUmBZoYgAPXGIOABMYeGQUUIjouI0krOQrAOXoABFEGpCO3BjgaHW3AAYUVB3C8A8UiBdrTRy9O66Ga9e4of7oIHQEHcJFBLxCHiQ9ztdE+O7+FCyBTQ+p3RTXImonECDFk64OEgQ5TrNBomnCO7M6CTaAABR4bBIPAI0AA5OtRdAdmxiDBjMENjEUZwwcxRexqd5RPjRcoUEA)

Comment: In my case they actually did have a common static member, but I made Constructor<T> an interface and it worked (In my case I didn't even need a parameter, it was a specific list of classes). Another difference is that it doesn't work for abstract classes - i.e., I can pass the constructor of an abstract class to `typeof T` parameter, but not to `Constructor<T>` and there doesn't seem to be a way to generalize it to allow abstract classes - so I had to make one parent class non-abstract - still better than to have a long list of typeofs. Thank you.