# Why class can not be treated as constrcutor?

Tags: typescript

From TS

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

Say, I have a class Foo,

```
class Foo {}
```

`InstanceType<Foo>` gives **never**, and `InstanceType<typeof Foo>` gives **Foo**. So my question is why Foo is not treated as new-able thing?

Comment: Because the *type* named `Foo` describes an instance of the class (if you want a value of type `Foo` you would be unhappy if someone gave you the class constructor, right?), while the *value* named `Foo` is the class constructor, whose type is not `Foo`, but `typeof Foo`, essentially the same as `new()=>Foo`.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript/50396312#50396312) explains this, but I guess the question isn’t exactly a duplicate.  There’s probably an existing question somewhere though; still looking...