# TS Design Philosophy - Does the 'typeof' keyword exist purely as a formality?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Take this example:

```
const MyArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];

type Person = typeof MyArray[number]; //<-- Line of Interest
```

Were it written as `type Person = myArray[number]`, in theory, it should still work because in a "type declaration context", all Javascript states can only exist as their type.

In otherwords, TS should know given the context of `type X =...` that `myArray1` is referring to the `type` and not the `JS value`.

Given the above; is there a reason why we need to use the `typeof` keyword except as a formality to more explicitly differentiate TS and JS values?

Comment: Some types are also values - for example, `class Foo {}` then `Foo` is a type but also a value, and `typeof Foo` is a different type.

Comment: I read a comment about this in another thread, but I didn't really quite understand. What exactly is the difference between `type = Foo` and `type = typeof Foo`?

Comment: You can write `let obj: Foo = new Foo();` whereas you would write `let cls: typeof Foo = Foo;`.

Comment: So basically it's the difference between an `instance` and the `class`? That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript/50396312) is different but the answer is largely the same: it is quite possible to use the same name for a value and for an *unrelated* type.  So `X` and `typeof X` may be completely different types. I could imagine a compiler warning *suggesting* replacing `Foo` with `typeof Foo` or vice versa, but having the compiler automagically reinterpret depending on context would be like having it interpret `obj.x` as `obj[x]` depending on context: nondeterministic and spooky.