# TypeScript notation for both "is object" and non-null

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a utility function like this, mainly to get around the annoyance that `typedef null` is `'object'`.

```
export function isObject(a: any): a is object {
  return a && (typeof a === 'function' || typeof a === 'object');
}
```

Instead of declaring the return type of this function `boolean`, you can use `a is object`, which is essentially a `boolean` too, but it assists type inference so that TypeScript knows that, if this function is true, `a` can be treated as an `object` without further type checking or casting.

I'd like to additionally declare that `a` is not null, but I can't find syntax that works.

```
export function isObject(a: any): a is NonNullable<object> {
  return a && (typeof a === 'function' || typeof a === 'object');
}
```

This at least has the advantage that it parses, but it doesn't help TypeScript infer that `a` is non-null.

I've tried other things that don't parse, like `a is object & !null` or `a is object & null: never` -- none of things work.

Is there a way to declare what I want to declare?

[image]

Comment: Typescript has a [strict null check](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro/strictnullchecks) option. You don't need to try to create a user defined type guard for it.

Comment: Why exactly do you want an `a is object` type guard?

Comment: Because the type guard assists in type inference. A better example might be with `a is number`. If you have an a function `foo(a: number | string)` and inside you have a test `if (isNumber(a)) b += a` TypeScript knows to allow this math without objection, without having to do `b += a as number`, etc., as long as `isNumber()` returns `a is number`.

Comment: Sure, I'm just wondering why you would want `object` specifically as a type guard, since there is not much you can safely do with just a plain `object`.

Comment: It's in a case where TypeScript knows that if the value is an object, then it's also a specific interface. I noticed code highlighting after my `isObject` test that meant "be careful, this variable might be null", when I knew it really couldn't be null.

Comment: @Jared, because I'd like the function declaration to do the whole job by itself, regardless of whether strict null checks are in effect.

Comment: @kshetline then you probably just want to turn on strict mode and strictNullChecks?

Comment: @Evert, as I said to Jared, I'd like the declaration to do the whole job, regardless of strictNullChecks being active or not.

Comment: Please post the code from your image as actual text (see [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for why) and ideally make sure the code constitutes a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found notation that does what I want:

```js
export function isObject(a: any): a is Record<string | number | symbol, any> {
  return a && (typeof a === 'function' || typeof a === 'object');
}
```

Not only does this express the non-nullness of `a` when the function returns `true`, but it allows me to access arbitrary properties on `a` without getting errors that the properties don't exist, which happens with `a is object` as the function return type.

```js
if (isObject(a)) {
  console.log(a.foo); // No error that property `foo` doesn't exist on `a`
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With [`--strictNullChecks` turned off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-off), there's no way to have the compiler help you guard against `null` or `undefined`, since any possibly-`null` value will be treated the same as if it were non-`null`:

```
function foo(x: {a: string} | null) {
  x.a.toUpperCase(); // error if and only if --strictNullChecks is enabled
}
```

So the only way to proceed is to [turn `--strictNullChecks` on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-on) so that the compiler can actually tell the difference between `null` and non-`null` values.  I will assume from here on out that this is the case.

---

The type guard function you are using is already guarding against `null` by returning `a is object`.  [**The `object` type in TypeScript**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) (which starts with a lowercase `o`, not to be confused with the `Object` type) **refers only to non-`null` and non-`undefined` object types**:

```
const bar: object = null; // error!
//    ~~~ <-- null is not assignable to object
```

Please note the difference between the *string* `"object"` returned by the JavaScript `typeof` operator at *runtime* and the TypeScript *type* `object`.  At runtime, `typeof null` returns `"object"`, whereas in the type system `typeof null` is `null`, not `object`.  It's potentially confusing because identical or similar identifiers can mean quite different things depending on whether you are looking at *values* or *types*.  You can read [one of my other <strike>diatribes</strike> answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for more details about that.

---

Again, if `--strictNullChecks` is enabled, the `object` type already excludes `null`. Therefore you should be able to just use your original type guard function returning `a is object`.  Here's an example:

```
function baz(x: {a: string} | null) {
  if (isObject(x)) {
    x.a.toUpperCase(); // no error now
  } else {
    const y: null = x; // also no error
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgeQEYCsCm0AUAhgFyKFgCeAlKYcionNnlIgN4CwAUIogE44oIPkjoAyMYnxQKABxxxgZRAF41iAOShIsBBsQAfA4hnzFytSs1Nc0DVQDc3AL7du26PCTA4cfAA9SNhJEFCg+GDAAc2dDRDAQABtEqnZuXn8AOkJMqDgAVVl5PgBhQhQcfEdEAHoaxBw+Pjg+ZCVyABNGMESKNsQAWgGwiOgAOSTEkoALPABrBlQGsEIMRJwOlzcuCAQwxAxCPlIbFlV4yYda+sbmvgBCbjreXgA-d8QAHiGL5Pp4uCscooGBRFZrHAmOCMZjQbbucCeBAHQgALwCQRCI0iMTiCWSqU4PH6+FQmFsUACVEJ6ReWRyeUKxTKFSqV2eYGhtxaAIA7rTYjhEhU0sTeLswPsKKR8Ylzv52fVCMLoZyGk0WgKXEA)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `Exclude` with a generic type parameter:

```
function nonNullObject<T>(x: T): x is Exclude<T, null | undefined> & object {
    return x && (typeof x === 'object' || typeof x === 'function');
}
```

Example usage: inside the `if` statement, `number` and `null` are eliminated from the type of `x` by control-flow type narrowing.

```
declare let x: Record<string, number> | number | null;

if(nonNullObject(x)) {
    x // Record<string, number>
}
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGBA5EAbDB5ARgKwFNoAeAFQD4AKADwC5EyBKBmxGAZ0QFEaIMQAE0LkANMkwZEAH0ThhwGGEKCKiAGSI4BYlEQBvAFCITiAE6EoIM0jbrNVKAE8ADoTjBEbALy-EAcm0iaH8ZWWc3Dy9EX28A0EhYBH8mAG5DAF9DQ2F+AEMLRAxLLwYAJWI4M0ESDigzJQBzcTAQAFtcQjM1WVaOrpkJLHTDGGAqFDB0LDxgqFomJgNjUzYAejXECogqmrqGsGaJfu7MwyA)

Comment: Thanks. This looks good, and is probably correct, but maybe IntelliJ's editor isn't smart enough to recognize the non-nullness, because the warning remains. (I added a picture to my post.) Oh, as if you think this is a fair question I had, would you do me the favor of canceling the downvote my question got? :-)

Comment: I just discovered the shorter syntex `Exclude<object, null>` works as well.

Comment: `object` already excludes `null`.  And since `object` is not a union type, `Exclude<object, null>` is just `object`.