# Parse String to Enum in Typescript using Strict mode enabled

Tags: typescript

When using TypeScript and `strict` enabled I have the enum:

```
export enum Policy {
  Admin,
  Editor
}
```

Then on a class I have:

```
policy?: Policy;

setPolicy(policy: string) {
  this.policy = Policy[policy];
}
```

I need to define the policy variable from a string.

When using `strict` and try to compile I get the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#enum) object named `Policy` is not known to have values at every `string` key; only the specific [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) `"Admin"` and `"Editor"` can be safely used.  I assume you're not trying to support someone calling `setPolicy("RandomString")`, right?  So one way to fix this is to only allow the `policy` argument to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of those types:

```
setPolicy(policy: "Admin" | "Editor") {
    this.policy = Policy[policy];
}
```

Of course you don't want to have to edit that line every time you add or otherwise modify the keys of `Policy`.  So you can use the [`keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) to get the union of keys from the type of the `Policy` object.  Note that the type of the `Policy` object is not `Policy`, but `typeof Policy` which uses the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator).  See [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript) for a long <strike>rant</strike> explanation about the difference between types and values in TypeScript.   So you can do this:

```
setPolicy(policy: keyof typeof Policy) {
    this.policy = Policy[policy];
}
```

The type `keyof typeof Policy` is the same as `"Admin" | "Editor"`, as you can see by inspecting it:

```
new Foo().setPolicy("Admin");
// setPolicy(policy: "Admin" | "Editor"): void
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/KYOwrgtgBACg9gGwJYGMCeUDeBYAUFAqAQQBMIkQAaPQqAURKQBc4AnPAXzzxQQEMAzgKgAxOHCw1CAB0So0AfgBcsOegDc3fIQHAm8ZOgAUsw2hUBrYGjgAzKEzTTgd1WYCUk7bQJMAFkgCAHSm8lAAvG7yANqh6AC6mt5QXLipWiDAAO6i4kbuQbr6amhGAESk5CBl7kkA9HVQRQbyJiUqFWQUZVAAPlBlDMxsNSoAbnBIJEA)