# Cannot assign enum to object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

Could you explain why the following does not work?

```
enum Types {
  T1 = "T1",
  T2 = "T2"
}

const something = {
  bool: true,  // some other initial value
  text: "abc", // some other initial value
  type: Types  // nothing yet, but has to be of type Types
}

const type1: Types = Types.T1  // OK

something.type = Types.T1  // error Type 'Types' is not assignable to type 'typeof Types'.ts(2322)
something.type = type1  // error Type 'Types' is not assignable to type 'typeof Types'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Is this a typo?  What exactly is your intent when you write `const something = {type: Types}`?  Are you aware that this is just a JavaScript object?  It has the same effect (at runtime) as `const something = {}; something.type = Types;`.  Are you trying to do that?  If so, why?  If not, what are you trying to do?  What would you like `something` to be initialized to?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you don't quite understand the difference between types and values in TypeScript?  Does [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript) clear anything up?

Comment: @jcalz Hi jcalz, I am trying to define an object `something` that starts with nothing but can have a property `type` that is of type `Types`. I updated my question to show my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const something = {
  bool: true,
  text: "abc",
  type: Types
}
```

The type of `something.type` is being inferred to be `typeof Types`, because you're assigning it the *value* `Types`, which is the sole value of type `typeof Types`. If you want to neglect to assign the value at first, you need to make the type nullable.

```
const something: {bool: boolean, text: string, type: null | Types} = {
  bool: true,
  text: "abc",
  type: null
}
```

We need an explicit type signature because, without it, the type of `something.type` is inferred to be `null`.

Comment: Ah thank you this means sense. But can I skip the type definitions before the = and just do so inside the object?