# Using `enum` in ternary operator TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I am trying to set an object with a ternary operator based on a config value and an `enum`

```
import { config } from 'src/config'
import {logLevelEnum} from 'a-package-installed'

const someObject = {
  logLevel: config.logLevel ? logLevelEnum[config.logLevel] : logLevelEnum.NOTHING,
}
```

The `enum` is basically this:

```
export enum logLevelEnum {
  NOTHING = 0,
  ERROR = 1,
  WARN = 2,
  INFO = 4,
  DEBUG = 5,
}
```

But I get the compilation error:

```sh
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
logLevel: config.logLevel ? logLevelEnum[config.logLevel] : logLevelEnum.NOTHING,
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But I don't understand why it says that the index expression is supposed to be `number` since is an `enum`.

Can someone explain to me why and how can I achieve what I need?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a typo while you declared `logLevel` but use it as `logLevelEnum`?

Comment: your code does now show what `logLevelEnum` is and also not what `config.logLevel` is... I guess that `config.logLevel`  is NOT a number, but should be

Comment: What's the type of `config.logLevel`?

Comment: `config.logLevel` is a string, before I used TS it was working ok, maybe there was an implicit cast? Also about the `logLevel` being used wrong, I edited, my bad. I am "paraphrasing" the code for brevity 

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `config.logLevel` is of type `string` while there is actually only a subset of valid strings.

So declare `config.logLevel` as a union type: `'NOTHING' | 'ERROR' | 'WARN' | 'INFO' | 'DEBUG'`

This union type doesn't seem to be generatable from the `enum` according to this: [Generic type to get enum keys as union string in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript)

Comment: I am confused tho, if I make it a union of string, it would still be a `string` but the compiler is saying it should be a `number`? The other problem is that I do not control the types of the `config.level` so I am not sure what to do in that case.

Comment: Don't mind the error saying that it should be a `number` this is not true

Comment: If you don't control `config.logLevel` then cast the type like this: `logLevelEnum[config.logLevel as 'NOTHING' | 'ERROR' | 'WARN' | 'INFO' | 'DEBUG']`

Answer (score 0):

Related [Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20hQNQqMIiHHxBAkpGxXhQCIk%20J0JmBeBUHpwALvZHWaB0Kgs%20J6NBECIBQBlKOUwriAuQLNJ7n2Q0UGt1hvN1sGdud9roi2YyFsOziSn2wHBPG50C%20ikBpjBzDUkSZ4ngBXplAb-1MbugXMH0mYTMmcP6HAx9duKjPvA4bOBndllkuStqz0IdG0yMwJSYccoEvCg-AMABCUAJQEA8cHDRABSQlBYMpUAAB9QAEDtCxEEwBQAfn7TNgPrUDwMg4iu0qKc4SteR2KRZcQlQIiqDwMQU30cA8AANVogUojNWFLVOFjMjgcBqRwgxfmpFjLVSepgAAKm0%20pQG00A2BQcRwBLE91ywAk%20PLACQXTNxbLZPwAiM-1EDjRBWDYCy9AneNE30wzr0UoySR0TMqGgAdP2w0d9Bfc4aHAMNq3-cAqydc1WPOIKMnyjI2C-d98WEI5GCTdxqQAIhyApihKar8NAaqmhaRomoI6rbU6lqpmyXrqqWNZGrygqMhEDgwU8jyQMw%20VDFsWBhCC4B6gOAd5Xk5bJykuJtpQaLQGS1KnMy9SkmXDIdL0noMmC9gHMzYzcGgRgLO4INwBs9LAIshalvAZ4XqiwThP%20pJDCHIRVvW4FIokIt9A05i9unBEtoUzitN0vLkvAeAa1AWA-OeT9HJe4yCXXHBwDcXDoAifdORQCV9yJ2KnOMSB4AJIhdAkOMpUYPLehQdwMKcogXMzcnnsO6miAEam5dTMwDsvRm5rV8xAfmAykJQuM%20IEetEHsLNqKTAArCKLOhlBMs5uSFNAZT9GB4rn24ARJYg5N7E-SkODy3IcB0MnWR8GWr0eoPxBoSqM0s8QkY078nYrC6zGeZDMzy6g8FNryLfZ79TWddHkgIoiCyLUyBXOUBTlrkiG6M2mU2z5Jv2vONQG1gGFN%20PLQ6-JNv05glosFoqLZ0cXaavX2GyIb30HrNlcOcVx3GwU5yPI1S8sPGlCFIEBGU4dLo45LkeT5QVhVFcUpRlYACWQaLtRCqQb-ZAIhhFCGA0EqPAKpVSmC8tmHAhhuCbx8JSUed0Db2RegSIumAUwHDTkkZ4WAsrSS%20HVIopRm5FRMCnXB4Rvyt3riWX4oBYZ3QwcrbBiMRDIzTIfQhLpYAcBIQ1Zcuxgi-XlLkCslR0rnTRqxZcYikgAGkUpJkqCdTK4jWT-CAA)

## Some basics

You can access your enum in different ways:

1. `logLevelEnum.WARN` = `2`: by the enum directly
2. `logLevelEnum['WARN']` = `2`: via index operator
3. `logLevelEnum[2]` = `WARN`: get the enum-name from an enum-value
   This works because typescript creates a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings)

When you try to access an invalid enum, you get `undefined` at runtime. Typescript tries to avoid this situation and gives you a compile error when possible to avoid this:

1. `logLevelEnum.warning`: *Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'typeof logLevelEnum'.*
2. `logLevelEnum['warning']` = `undefined`: *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.*

   - this is maybe a little confusing, as it seems to indicate that you can
     only use number as index - which is not true - see 2. above
   - but the basic statement is right: typescript cannot guarantee that this expression returns a valid enum, thus the type of this expression is `any` (and not `logLevelEnum` or `logLevelEnum | undefined`, etc.)
     Hint: you can see the type when you hover over the `invalidStringIndex` variable in the [Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20hQNQqMIiHHxBAkpGxXhQCIk%20J0JmBeBUHpwALvZHWaB0Kgs%20J6NBECIBQBlKOUwriAuQLNJ7n2Q0UGt1hvN1sGdud9roi2YyFsOziSn2wHBPG50C%20ikBpjBzDUkSZ4ngBXplAb-1MbugXMH0mYTMmcP6HAx9duKjPvA4bOBndllkuStqz0IdG0yMwJSYccoEvCg-AMABCUAJQEA8cHDRABSQlBYMpUAAB9QAEDtCxEEwBQAfn7TNgPrUDwMg4iu0qKc4SteR2KRZcQlQIiqDwMQU30cA8AANVogUojNWFLVOFjMjgcBqRwgxfmpFjLVSepgAAKm0%20pQG00A2BQcRwBLE91ywAk%20PLACQXTNxbLZPwAiM-1EDjRBWDYCy9AneNE30wzr0UoySR0TMqGgAdP2w0d9Bfc4aHAMNq3-cAqydc1WPOIKMnyjI2C-d98WEI5GCTdxqQAIhyApihKar8NAaqmhaRomoI6rbU6lqpmyXrqqWNZGrygqMhEDgwU8jyQMw%20VDFsWBhCC4B6gOAd5Xk5bJykuJtpQaLQGS1KnMy9SkmXDIdL0noMmC9gHMzYzcGgRgLO4INwBs9LAIshalvAZ4XqiwThP%20pJDCHIRVvW4FIokIt9A05i9unBEtoUzitN0vLkvAeAa1AWA-OeT9HJe4yCXXHBwDcXDoAifdORQCV9yJ2KnOMSB4AJIhdAkOMpUYPLehQdwMKcogXMzcnnsO6miAEam5dTMwDsvRm5rV8xAfmAykJQuM%20IEetEHsLNqKTAArCKLOhlBMs5uSFNAZT9GB4rn24ARJYg5N7E-SkODy3IcB0MnWR8GWr0eoPxBoSqM0s8QkY078nYrC6zGeZDMzy6g8FNryLfZ79TWddHkgIoiCyLUyBXOUBTlrkiG6M2mU2z5Jv2vONQG1gGFN%20PLQ6-JNv05glosFoqLZ0cXaavX2GyIb30HrNlcOcVx3GwU5yPI1S8sPGlCFIEBGU4dLo45LkeT5QVhVFcUpRlYACWQaLtRCqQb-ZAIhhFCGA0EqPAKpVSmC8tmHAhhuCbx8JSUed0Db2RegSIumAUwHDTkkZ4WAsrSS%20HVIopRm5FRMCnXB4Rvyt3riWX4oBYZ3QwcrbBiMRDIzTIfQhLpYAcBIQ1Zcuxgi-XlLkCslR0rnTRqxZcYikgAGkUpJkqCdTK4jWT-CAA)
3. `logLevelEnum[999]` = `undefined`:

   - unfortunately we don't get a compile error here, but it is obviously not a valid index
   - the type of this expression is `string`! But actually it can also be `undefined`.
     Hint: when you activate the typescript-compiler option [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), then the type will be `string|undefined` which is more accurate

## Answer to your question

As I understand your question

- `config.logLevel` is of type `string` and not under your control.
  If it were under your control, the type should be `logLevelEnum` and everything would be easier: `logLevelEnum[logLevelEnum]` is then guaranteed to be a valid enum (at compile time)
- you want to get a valid log-level: when `config.logLevel` is valid, you want to use it, otherwise you want to use `logLevelEnum.NOTHING`

So basically you need a function like this (which you call with `config.logLevel`):

```js
function getValidLogLevelEnum(logLevelName: string): logLevelEnum {
  /**
   * we need the correct type so that typescript will allow the index access
   * note: we must cast the string to `keyof typeof logLevelEnum`
   *       which resolves to: "NOTHING" | "ERROR" | "WARN" | "INFO" | "DEBUG"
   *       i.e. all valid enum-names
   */
  const enumName = logLevelName as keyof typeof logLevelEnum;
  /**
   * now that we have the correct type of the enum-name, we can get the enum-value
   */
  const configEnum = logLevelEnum[enumName];
  /**
   * keep in mind, that we were cheating a little bit in the type-expression above
   * We told typesript that we are sure that enumName is a valid enum-name,
   * but actually it is just the value of the logLevelName string, which could be anything.
   * Thus, typescript now thinks that configEnum is of type logLevelEnum, but 
   * actually it is `logLevelEnum | undefined` (undefined when logLevelEnum is not a valid enum-name)
   * 
   * This is the reason why use the nullish coalescing operator (??):
   * see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing
   * 
   * so we return configEnum, or logLevelEnum.NOTHING (when configEnum is undefined) 
   */
  return configEnum ?? logLevelEnum.NOTHING;
}
```