# Can I remove `typeof` operator in type

Tags: typescript

I have a problem about type manipulation

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

function exampleFn1<T extends Record<string, A>>( t: T ) {
    for( const v of Object.values( t ) )
        new v();   // TS2351: This expression is not constructable.    
                   // Type 'A' has no construct signatures.
}

function exampleFn2<T extends Record<string, typeof A>>( t: T ) {
    for( const v of Object.values( t ) )
        new v();   // ok
}
```

Although there is no error by the second method, I want to get `A` instead of `typeof A`, how can I do

```js
type A = typeof Example;

type B = RemoveTypeof<A>; // Expect type B = Example
```

Comment: Can you be more clear

Comment: There's no "remove `typeof`" operator as such, and it's not even particularly sensible, see [this rant/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) explaining the `typeof` operator.  You could write `type B = InstanceType<A>`, but that only works for class constructors; see [examples](https://tsplay.dev/WzLb1N).  Can you explain the exact use case?  Is it only for class constructors?

Comment: Perhaps your use case is: `Record<string, U extends A>`?

Comment: I don't understand your new use case; `exampleFn1` can't really work because `v` will be a class instance and not a constructor.  Your `exampleFn2` works fine, although I'd probably say `new () => A` instead of `typeof A` here (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQeEnw)).  But in neither case does `InstanceType<typeof A>` help much here.  What, specifically, is the issue?  Can you describe it with both words and with a [mre]?

Answer (score 3):

Use `InstanceType`:

```
type B = InstanceType<A>;
```

or simply

```
type B = A["prototype"];
```

[Demo link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAvgWAChCAXATxUwEFoBeaMigewDM5FUMBuQk8zAIQCMtaAEkAdhGJhxwdABU+AHkoA+bgQYCATCMoBtAEQoATo2Lm+hgLoagA)

Comment: Oh, thanks a million. I edited the exact use case, is there a better way to achieve it?