# Passing generic enum type as a parameter to a function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I have two string enums that have the same variants, but have different string values.

They get passed to the same initial function, which accepts the entire enum (which I think I can do using `typeof`, but each enum should have a different callback. What seems to be the best way to type the initial function?

This code that I have doesn't work, as it complains that I can't use `typeof` with my `T` generic parameter.

```js
enum OpsA {
    Start = 'a_start',
    Stop = 'a_stop'
}

enum OpsB {
    Start = 'b_start',
    Stop = 'b_stop'
}

type EitherOps = OpsA | OpsB

function doSomething <T extends EitherOps, U extends typeof T>(action: U, callback: (a: T) => void) {
    console.log(action.Start)
    callback(action.Start)
    console.log(action.Stop)
    callback(action.Stop)
}

// does something special for OpsA
const callbackForA = (a: OpsA) => console.log(a)
// does something else special for OpsB
const callbackForB = (b: OpsB) => console.log(b)

doSomething(OpsA, callbackForA)
doSomething(OpsB, callbackForB)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBkgdm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that works perfectly, thanks so much for that!  if you don't mind, could I throw you a curveball and ask why that works, [but this doesn't](https://tsplay.dev/mb0X2w)?

Comment: Because `action` and not `selectedOperation` is the enum object with `Start` and `Stop` properties?  I mean what makes you think `selectedOperation.Start` exists?  I'd change it to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp9yMW) unless I'm confused about what you're doing.  Anyway I will write up an answer to the question as asked when I get a chance; it might not be until tomorrow.

Comment: thanks that was very helpful, I completely messed up which TS Playground that I needed to send. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `T` is a type and not a value, so `typeof T` is a category error.  Your confusion probably stems from the fact that [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) declarations bring into scope both a named value and a named type, and the names happen to be the same.  But there's no general rule that a value and a type with the same name have any relationship to each other.

For example, `enum OpsA { /* ... */ }` declares both the value `OpsA` (an object with property keys `Start` and `Stop`) and the type `OpsA` (a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of the property values of the enum object).  When you write `typeof OpsA` as a type you are talking about the type of the enum object, while when you write `OpsA` as a type you are talking about the type of the enum object's property values.

But the fact that the type `OpsA` is the property type of the object type `typeof OpsA` cannot be generalized the way you are presumably trying to do.  There is no rule that says "given the type `T` there is a type `typeof T` whose properties are of type `T`."  See [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for more information.

---

Okay, if you can't write `U extends typeof T`, what *can* you do?  You want `U` to be an object type whose property keys are `"Start"` or `"Stop"`.  Let's get a type for those keys first.  Since both `ObjA` and `ObjB` value have these keys, we can write that as either `keyof typeof ObjA` or `keyof typeof ObjB`:

```
type OpsKeys = keyof typeof OpsA;
// type OpsKeys = "Start" | "Stop"
```

If we want to say that `U` should be an object type with keys of `OpsKeys` and values of type `T`, then we can use [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype): `U extends Record<OpsKeys, T>`.  Like this:

```
function doSomething<
  T extends EitherOps,
  U extends Record<OpsKeys, T>
>(action: U, callback: (a: T) => void) {
  console.log(action.Start)
  callback(action.Start)
  console.log(action.Stop)
  callback(action.Stop)
}
```

Now everything works as desired inside `doSomething()`.  Let's make sure that it also works for callers:

```
doSomething(OpsA, callbackForA) // okay
doSomething(OpsB, callbackForB) // okay
doSomething(OpsA, callbackForB) // error
```

Looks good.  The compiler warns if you pass in a `callback` argument that's inappropriate for the `action` argument.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDgZwIJQN4FgBQUoGUAuAhgE75QC8UA5IQPoJGlUA0WOBA9nBdXQ11SwBfLFlCRYiAEJo2eRmUpUARvQUs5nbktX84gzCMxZ8ATzjAoAUQCW+ABbBi8BDxcoAPpIRTRmMxbeANLApq6UANahHABmUAHAsd5IANxYAPTp8eaWLiFhPABEBCT4hVBexfhchX4xYCAAxvg2HCBQACYcuBwQwA42IADmADxyACpQwAAe+KAdrrYOTi6s2FAAqlOz864ASsCNHMQdI3mhCMxQ4wB8WDcAFITNrSAAXJtXjYQANj-KzwiHyeH3GAEoKDcoAA3Dg2DoQjDrI4gBAcH7AAB0Pw4QyeLzamJKpDBcm+fwBjQi+JahOJ+FJyLaaIx2NxNNeROqcEZOHJ-0BHLp3MZRgyWS6wFcaL6A2GUAQFkaNl+UBix2SWBRDCg-MpEQAYscUJQQckIeQodr0VicXjCIzMp0OFKFb1+vZBkMpj8EJZFYcVT81RqXL5MNqyHrAUbiDJTcoPmGLVbmTa2XjlIysF0erLPcMHu4vr8BVTY0gIU6OBFCKYc913XK8WGSxSY8cpFWsjW6w28x6vUXEEg22XDZ3u1NiMRjlggA)