# TypeScript: a string of characters of <type>

Tags: typescript, types

Maybe I'm losing it.

I've got a list of possible nucleotides and a corresponding `type`:

```js
const DNA = ['G', 'C', 'T', 'A'] as const;

type DNA = typeof DNA[number];
```

Now, a DNA `strand` could be a string of any of the characters (GCTA), in any combination, of any length. What's important here, is that each individual character is of type `DNA`.

If I `split('')` this `strand`, I want to get an array of characters, each of these characters of type `DNA`, e.g,

```js
const strand: ??? = "GACATAGACGCGTTAG";
const DNAstring: DNA[] = strand.split('');
```

How do I type the `strand` in this case?

If I type it as a `string`, TypeScript gets understandably upset: `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("G" | "C" | "T" | "A")[]'`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use type assertion like this: ` strand.split('') as DNA[]` but I don't know if it will accomplish something.

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to a string that consists only of characters in some set.  There is a proposal for regular-expression validated string types, see [ms/TS#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160).  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAKxvw) goes through your various options, none of which are great.

Comment: If this addresses your question fully I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, I think this is it, more or less. While not perfectly ideal, should do the job! Thank you! Oh, and if you could write up an answer, double thank you! :)

Comment: @jcalz I haven't found a place in the handbook that discusses type alias names shadowing value names (e.g. `DNA` in the question), yet the compiler seems to happily merge them. Do you have a link?

Comment: It's not shadowing, it's just a different namespace.  I've discussed this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) but I don't know if the handbook mentions it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no specific type in TypeScript that represents strings that consist only of characters in some set.  There's a longstanding suggestion to support [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) validated string types; see [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) for the current open issue on the subject.  If such types existed, you could probably write

```
// NOT VALID TS, don't do this:
type DNAStrand = /[GCTA]*/;
```

and be done with it.  Alas, this is not possible (yet?).  If you want to (slightly) increase the chance that this will be implemented in the future, you might go to that issue, give it a , and describe your use case, why it's compelling (something tells me DNA strands are not a major use case for most people), and why the current solutions (I present some below) aren't sufficient.

---

Currently, TypeScript has [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), which allow you to perform some character-wise manipulation of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). One might naively try to represent `DNAStrand` as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the empty string plus a single `DNA` followed by another `DNAStand`... sort of a [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) syntax representation:

```
// NOT VALID TS, don't do this:
type DNAStrand = "" | `${DNA}${DNAStrand}` // can't do this
```

Alas, this is seen as circular in an invalid way; unions are computed eagerly, and the compiler would bomb out at some point, so it complains.

You *can* make a union of all valid DNA Strand string literals up to some length, using a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types):

```
type RepeatLessThan<N extends number, T extends string, A extends string[] = [""]> =
  N extends A['length'] ? A[number] : RepeatLessThan<N, T, [`${T}${A[0]}`, ...A]>

// and this works for short lengths
type DNAStandUpToThree = RepeatLessThan<4, DNA>;
/* type DNAStandUpToThree = "" | "G" | "C" | "T" | "A" | "GG" | "GC" | "GT" | "GA" | "CG" | "CC" | "CT" | 
 "CA" | "TG" | "TC" | "TT" | "TA" | "AG" | "AC" | "AT" | "AA" | "GGG" | "GGC" | "GGT" | "GGA" | "GCG" | "GCC" 
 | "GCT" | "GCA" | "GTG" | "GTC" | "GTT" | "GTA" | "GAG" | "GAC" | "GAT" | "GAA" | "CGG" | "CGC" | "CGT" | 
 "CGA" | "CCG" | "CCC" | "CCT" | "CCA" | "CTG" | "CTC" | "CTT" | "CTA" | "CAG" | "CAC" | "CAT" | "CAA" | 
 "TGG" | "TGC" | "TGT" | "TGA" | "TCG" | "TCC" | "TCT" | "TCA" | "TTG" | "TTC" | "TTT" | "TTA" | "TAG" | 
 "TAC" | "TAT" | "TAA" | "AGG" | "AGC" | "AGT" | "AGA" | "ACG" | "ACC" | "ACT" | "ACA" | "ATG" | "ATC" | 
 "ATT" | "ATA" | "AAG" | "AAC" | "AAT" | "AAA" */
```

But TypeScript can only represent unions of a size up to something like 100,000 members.  Your example string is 16 characters long, and so you'd need at least 4^16 ≈ 4 billion members to represent that.  There's no useful way to enumerate these.  If you try, you'll have problems:

```
// VALID TS, but STILL DON'T DO THIS:
type DNAStandUpToSixteen = RepeatLessThan<17, DNA> // , eventually error with
// "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent"
```

---

Instead, the closest we can get using template literal types is to make `DNAStrand` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that *verifies* or *checks* a string literal to see if it's valid.  This saves us from having to enumerate every possible valid strand, but it has the downside that anything that deals with these types needs to itself be generic:

```
type VerifyDNAStrand<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? 
    F extends DNA ? VerifyDNAStrand<R, `${A}${F}`> : `${A}${DNA}` : 
  A
```

You can't easily write `const x: DNAStrand = "ACT"`, you need `const x: DNAStrand<"ACT"> = "ACT"`.  So instead of annotating, it's easier to use a generic helper identity function:

```
const dnaStrand = <T extends string>(
  x: T extends VerifyDNAStrand<T> ? T : VerifyDNAStrand<T>) => x;

const goodStrand = dnaStrand("GATTACA"); // okay
const badStrand = dnaStrand("ATTACK OF THE CLONES"); // error
// -----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"ATTACK OF THE CLONES"' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// '"ATTACA" | "ATTACG" | "ATTACC" | "ATTACT"'
```

---

So that's great.  But the compiler's [definition for `String.prototype.split()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8636adbbb9ab47bb377bd89a3390a13b66df34d2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L475) is like

```
interface String {
    split(separator: string | RegExp, limit?: number): string[];
}
```

which always outputs `string[]` no matter what.  The compiler has no idea that `"ABC".split("")` produces `["A", "B", "C"]`.  So all the above work with `DNAStrand` doesn't fix your underlying issue:

```
const stillNotDNAstring: DNA[] = goodStrand.split(''); // error!
```

And so you fall back to needing a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere:

```
const dnaString = goodStrand.split('') as DNA[]; // okay
```

But that just means you've taken over from the compiler when it comes to type safety.  Nothing stops you from doing the wrong thing:

```
const oops = badStrand.split('') as DNA[]; // still okay
```

Possibly you could wrap your splitting code into a function where inside the function type safety needs to be manually handled, but then people could at least call it safely, kind of:

```
function splitStrand<T extends string>(
  x: T extends VerifyDNAStrand<T> ? T : VerifyDNAStrand<T>) {
  return x.split('') as DNA[];
}

const okay = splitStrand("GATTACA"); // okay
const bad = splitStrand("ATTACK OF THE CLONES"); // compiler error
```

So that's the closest I can think of when it comes to compile-time verification of DNA strand strings.  If you don't need compile time verification, but just some way to track the types, you can use runtime verification with a branded type or some other structure, as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720372/2887218) details.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgOQIIwLwwNoHIDiWA0MWAwgUQCplZJYC6MAhhDKJFANwBQnUAngA4BTeMjQw+QkADMRSDGACuAWwBGggE60unAPQ7xA4YiQBlKOoZgAJmPU6MOYuSS0AVDu16YxS1lgB3dQBLKGF1QWAFdQgggDdhUKV+ABsGUJhkkI0GZJhoYLAAcwhdfQkjZDMLazEAIlqYAB8YAAMAEgBvYwBfTuMqyytulpgvYF9YKxBxAAsgktKYAE0QBRZLFnC04QUwIPBmBX5xaYgQJWFkwSKoGZ5DGAAlQSE0gBlBCAhyGcsAHgQMEEAA9QtZmIpVBpCOQgaDrlZmPkgkVCCgQWDEXlzCjChh6OgMPVaAA+NCcGAwQEYhHMORYK43GZ0GAAfhgckhak0MAAXE8XoJ3p9vr8wACYYQMO0OuReh05AAGWjDQgAOg1LhJ3C8g1m8xg-hA6gA1swpMa8jNjbBGYVbiVyrIzIMAKr8cggH7hYToZ6vKAfL4-f4AFkIxhJXB0rgMQmdUDdHq9Mx9dQazVqOAzMFqxBztXIBaQBZw2aauccpaLFazJdrxHLmeI+YbNeaFLz9cz5CbufIrZ77f73dzSD7tSQg7Hw8no6zZdLVdrZdnZfnjgnjlbFMzjjXxA3ver06z5DXzlL46vp5wSDXSHnjYnjdPjeHncbT8bBZbb6cv6Hr+x5tm+57AU+14NlOv73rBo6dr2E69qevazr284DshLYFgO6FAbW57IQOuHgYRl6EVBHYjqhcGUfO44TuOp7jrO44MT+tZTixAFcQRmb3kxJEVp295sRRAlUWOMFcXRkn1u4Or6CoCiwLs+yQDA0h5EEABewihgAegAjAAbIw4QnNMKhBIUMAWuoszCKASRBFcjlQNM4T8OEEDXFAhBnDAvCrI5IIMEkVzYtUNgGmAICwIUIC4icixSCEhB6uYvApZ5MDeb5-kwCEjDMAwMDqeAhpubk4wKH5wWhSw5z8KpGgnDAMxCmpxx6osTr9Im1jup6JhBPC1xiP63VBqK-zGQA7BGyBkl4gC8G4ApLtrYA3TubYQgjxGAUAKDkyS8EC6jqJa-ghHcXi1AAosCPkihpMA+SAVgKMAnyMBVexVU6txpMVzCedMLkpCCHUFZ8-m1EpyyrDArjjGAsaBFkf2FNcGhBMAcYJL8sDxME6W-eV-AMOoUD4woqSOciRQZFkFjJIQKmwLcBpKAwJqfIsli8NzzPA2pfnMCVYCCIINh5WoMA49LwQEzkZxqtwToAGp41IvCDTFfywjS4LRbiaJwpiSI4sz6D1GSqAUjAxvwqbMoolI7UAGLyh77WPMMbIwF7lu0rIQc62T+uVOYgx-I8hAykg8o+y0ZL8kn8o9CM-JIIjKxrGjfhAkwbnnZj6SsNAMDAvyBt6nbU5FoQIVrNLsvNWwNd1zHhuTgBDtjgB0b6CgXXJEIjlSLswC01VaOMMkVyxEE2yzGkvLcFXkxgAwAw1OgRuh6bTOFCSAAUtfO8fWKR0Eev19YRtkuysL8nfD+93H5AkgAlGgZJgTaG3orEAn1942HQFYXeEDz51nPFOEsv92CjH0CAE0DBeCcBASoBgVgIFiGgXvWO1g4FiSnAAaRgAAeRDuQAAEg9bwbxqEIAeiYWoyDUEXSuuoRYABaQRQjhEiNEYIskAA-KR0iZGyLkRIxYSB1CFGUEVbSTosCTgQcQKhtDnaMOYaw9htQsCgxgPFWATAYiFF3ioKKeUqYWAuKERy6iHiLE0eQ-iM5nCcQEtoli2iixYERiGKAWBmCFC2LATmMAt4HFgNAGqCAErGFPj3OQBJQHgJIVYNUEAUghHPlgLAXCvB-EEU5Zqrl3KdSYOY6YQQrBCkNMTPIhSoDFNKTAKYv08rlVPizFxOREZ6iCq3eyp0YC4OACaDq7crApXKk6KxGg55gHiV3IhVQUroCSjkmK+SOldP-vU4w+IUFeHQZgwgixYnczKskIKRpTTmktLg-BuSjmZE6SU3++dkagHpjYQIDBjit0Zh05qzTipHWmOVaeYBZ5vX8F1SyKIYgwtuMIRFyLAYPAgAwT2fBzEyyxPLQQixeaKFOudMUVgrhWA5qpJyYB3qCBAFDZqwLGC2iFNXcYS9iqJKJYIM6hATQohsNITguL1ntJ+RAo+JssSnwvlfF2VsYAf2jqYXJz8g5v21brXVSqf7-w6E7cIx11BsuBN8opfzSqyAuZwbo2CElaQweddABTFW5LgXebRSDLloO9R6ruHyxB+pCLArRvjdF0IMcQFhbCOFlP0JDNy7UNC8O4EAA)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), but you can have the structural characteristics of a `string` while narrowing the assignability of the DNA strand type by creating a [branded](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) `string`.

Also, [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is somewhat complicated... it's probably simpler to use the string's [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) when collecting the bases into an array.

Here's a solution which provides those characteristics and also optional validation of the strand strings:

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEBUAsFNQFwJ4AdoGdQDMBOB7AtqAjgK5agCOxacAljgHYBcAUAMYOpygAiAcgIKgAvKADaAcn7iANKHEBhGXIDiS8eHEBdUAEN07epwDczRCh4Dh8ZNBwYL-UfWJ4ARtCyaTzEKABEAEJYOvQAJtChfqCcWDT0AOYsZrB8-ADKcMFhVjFx8aAAZKAA3sygoL4AknDi6DR4SDioqDSuADawGDhkOHAwZMnocDigkDoAbrB9NOhIuChYiCzlWNA6oQxtCKAA+qkZWaGMoMT0NJSwqAhuOG0m5b5QM-DQbW1DMKDsDTQdA2NcPqwGhwDw6YZkBA0V6hdCpaKZPLoAAUxFQU0gzzinDWoVAdn8MRCoQAdKgkG0QcjxOIAJR+WllMRpa6uW4kkFgiGaY7I2nCAB8oGqYPa0BFwQhAB5UgKTABfby+NL4WDEWiU2hoeAjGBtJCgADuIMgoHGOkpoXBdCYbDaenQ-GaHloDAAolhcGRoAAPUFhdAer0lJk4SaemjhUD0HR4WAiSTOxY2oPdcQK5jMDCnViu+i6JNcZG+ubHU4Aa3oOEN9FkeFQ8QA-MdcglaccHS70CWyKVyjR7MiAIQ9-l9XCG6PQSdO9HJ92e7rI+vxWkZtgcLihGMAJWg8V9VmAAD1RPx5MpwJoANQAEmASrAAFV0fBMUMRqxVuDYDoHAjDlkYl8SQPMLS2M0LUjH9dEBT52E4fF7AWLosDwEJWGgLMczzAsDmA5E4iQdUW0RBJZHNS0f2bUA2VuNZ6HbBx8OyPtQAHUBkUo6DQX5TtFmRbcdD3A8fRJUFOEI+hiLgWlZAAA0qehuLxeEiTCY4-FvYoiPVeU-HktcmVWOBSHzXSuD0ZjMmJdcfGfVAdAPFgN0MLh1LxEQ9BY0JqXkcB+FUIz7OFUFJTyXQAIitEIr-PxUJJRK7CiNocBwA04nGHBy21EE6jC8FuhYVDOIMRDXD0WACQ8-k2Iq9EjAqMA-H4KIAB9-Hkdr-GUbq-HAPxmHlTNfBfCLyW-PErnoOAdB9HUvm-UFdHzHRPR0bZqrI-JTjy0qxmCXMPFQflsHwSLW3yC1UBGTLstyuB8q5IrXPKyr0BEURErJGywi8JrOJavqutADq-F60H-AG2lRG0ABaI1MVYU1nhiYhc1IcDtkjaAZpoVgLQW1JYczTJtjY7zft8hQAuUAAtOlGuVcsaANFTrQYWjtnCDAdGINo4CZMr6JJVL4j82mGdkcRssZplKcOak6f8wKlEyKg1wBgA1KCrWWiyhY4EWxaVlXVGl2WjOGgm4GRzjfVqw3DBFjwvWLH0reYIA)

```ts
// The types from your question:
const DNA = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'] as const;
type DNA = typeof DNA[number];

// "Branded" string:
type DNAStrand = string & {
  // It's impossible for other types to have this property:
  readonly _DNAStrand: unique symbol;
  // This tells the compiler that the iterator yields DNA strings (use this instead of "strand.split('')")
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<DNA>;
};

// Some utilities to help with validation:
class AssertionError extends Error {
  override name = 'AssertionError';
}

function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new AssertionError(msg);
}

const dnaRegex = /^[ACGT]+$/;

// Use this to create a DNA strand, and optionally validate at the cost of performance
function asStrand (input: string, validate?: boolean): DNAStrand {
  if (validate) assert(dnaRegex.test(input), `Invalid DNA strand: "${input}"`);
  return input as DNAStrand;
}


// Usage:

const strand = asStrand('CTAG');

// Iterating a string using a "for...of" loop invokes its iterator:
for (const base of strand) {
  base; // "A" | "C" | "G" | "T"
}

// Using spread syntax to create an array of string units (characters) from a string also invokes its iterator:
const bases = [...strand]; // ("A" | "C" | "G" | "T")[] - which is structurally identical to DNA[]

try {
  asStrand('CTAGZ'); // Skip validation by default
  console.log('CTAGZ', 'ok');
  asStrand('ZCTAG', true); // Validate input
  console.log('ZCTAG', 'ok');
}
catch (ex) {
  console.error(ex);
}
```