# why the `interface` name the same as the `var`'s?

Tags: typescript

I saw this pattern today in the WebAssembly package and was confused about this usage.

1. Why is the interface name the same as the var name?
2. Any difference between `c1` and `c2`?
3. `new S({ a: 6 })`, How to understand the `S`, is it an interface or the var?

```
interface S {
  a: number,
}

declare var S: {
   b: number,
   new (value?: any): S;
}

const c1 = { a: 6 };
const c2 = new S({ a: 6 });
```

Comment: `declare var` creates a **value** named `S` that is constructable. `interface` creates a **type** named `S`. This type `S` is returned by the construct signature of the value `S`.

Comment: All type information is stripped after compilation, so for 3. the only option is the `var`. The `interface` cannot be used in runtime code.

Comment: @caTS `declare var S` will not create anything. Just tells the compiler that this *exists* and (hopefully) will be available when this code runs. It is just a way to enhance the ambient type context, e.g., when there is something declared globally but your piece of code does not include it. Or otherwise something comes from an outer scope the compiler cannot analyse.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values and types don't share a namespace in TypeScript, so in *general* there's no necessary relationship between a named value (like `var S`) and a named type (like `interface S`); they just happen to share a name.

However, when you write [a `class` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html), it brings into existence both a named value corresponding to the class constructor, and a named type corresponding to instances of the class.  This allows things like `const d: Date = new Date()`, where the first `Date` is the instance type, and where the second `Date` is the class constructor value.  (See [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218) for a long explanation of this)

So, if I were to happen to write this:

```
class S {
  a: number;
  static b: number = 1;
  constructor(value?: any) {
    this.a = (typeof value === "number") ? value : 123;
  }
}
```

It would create a value named `S` that's the class constructor, and a type named `S` which is an instance of that class.  The class constructor can be called via `new S(value)` where `value` is an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) parameter of [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), and it produces a value of type `S`.  A value of type `S` has an `a` property of type `number`.  Also note that the class constructor `S` has a [`static` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) named `b` of type `number`.

If you ask "is `S` a variable or a type" without more context, the answer is "it's both" or "it depends".

Anyway you can test its behavior like this:

```
console.log(S.b) // 1
const c1: S = { a: 6 };
console.log(c1.a) // 6
console.log(c1 instanceof S) // false
const c2: S = new S({ a: 6 });
console.log(c2.a) // 123
console.log(c2 instanceof S) // true
```

Note that `c1` is just some object with an `a` property, and is not necessarily an instance of the `S` class, even though it conforms to the `S` interface.  On the other hand, `c2` is definitely an instance of the `S` class, although its `a` property isn't necessarily related to the value of the `a` property passed into the constructor (after all that `value` argument can be `any` value, and the particular constructor implementation doesn't know that `value` has an `a` property and doesn't try to look for one).

---

Now, if I were to write a [declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for that class, I'd write this:

```
declare class S {
    a: number;
    static b: number;
    constructor(value?: any);
}
```

But another way to write this is to declare the `S` constructor as a variable of the appropriate type, and to declare an interface named `S` of the appropriate shape:

```
interface S {
  a: number,
}

declare var S: {
  b: number,
  new(value?: any): S;
}
```

That behaves essentially the same.  So you can think of the `var`/`interface` declaration pair above as being a "synonym" for the `class` declaration.

---

*Why* would someone write it this way?  Well, that's not completely obvious.  According to [microsoft/TypeScript#9154](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9154), older versions of TypeScript didn't let you [merge declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into the instance side of `class`es, so one would often leave it as an `interface` to allow this.  Nowadays that's not a concern anymore, really.

In *general*, the `var`/`interface` pair is more flexible, since there are still things you can do with `interface` merging that you can't do with `class` merging.  For example, you can give the `var` a type of another interface (say `declare var S: SConstructor; interface SConstructor { /*...*/ }`), and allow people to merge new members into the constructor later.  And `class` constructors can't be marked as callable without `new`, while `var`s can.

But none of that applies to the example you've given.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/PQKglgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDK6DeBYAKHXSQC50IBXAWwCN4AaQgX0MIBMYUAbJODAG58s5fEXS1yVOo0LEIMAO4AKId0owA-OSQQAngEpymANwtCIYGwI8kAZztZccklJr04Z8XahIoYFAk3GTh0AF50AEYvYhQAewgfOEoUKDi4VSR1LR19A2dxYigACzA7ADokcPRlKD0ABxg4hHQ1DXCwiIAiaQ8u-M1WrPbySIAmAGYY9FYCWcJQdE5bfnRbBycxYmIyCnd4aeIfPwCgvZDDtYSklLSMtpySPK9mdEtreMS47hhy7jiAObKTDlWj5YDAKKET4+NaRYzVHCudAANhmXhh31+-yBKEilXBkJR0OuWL+gOUePQkGOEDQzSwhPQyG4dhgJMSUDWYwREQUiiwyiRuzRzAMGNJP3JuLGBPQEKikw5djJOMpY2pnN09JamCZUGS7IIhCAA)