# Define type based on another type by omitting array of keys

Tags: typescript

I've got the following type:

```js
type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
```

and I'd like to define a type that's missing the fields listed in the string array

```js
const keysToDrop = ['a', 'c']
```

Thankfully, we have the `Omit` utility type for that, and we can do

```js
type client = Omit<MyType, 'a' | 'c'>
```

So now, I have to find a way to convert a `string[]` into a string literal type, say `'a' | 'c'`.

However, because Typescript needs all the type modifiers to be there at compile time, first I'd need to make the string array "unmodifiable" (a const array is always modifiable as any one of its elements is modifiable).

What I have now is

```js
// ensuring unmodifiability
const keysToDrop = ['a', 'c'] as const

// converting it to string literal
type MyNarrowedType = (typeof keysToDrop)[number]
```

I'd like find a way to make the conversion `(typeof keysToDrop)[number]` work with any `keysToDrop`.

Is there a way to generate a template that takes a `keysToDrop` as "input" and generates a `MyNarrowedType` based on that?

Something, written in a messed-up pseudo code, like:

```
type MyNarrowedType: (keysToDrop) => (typeof keysToDrop)[number]
```

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: You cannot make a generic type that takes a *value*, it can only take a *type*.  So you could write `type MyNarrowedType<T extends {[k: number]: any}> = T[number]` and write `MyNarrowedType<typeof keysToDrop>`, but there's no way to "push" `typeof` into the definition.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50376977/2887218.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: That does explain it, thank you! Also for pointing me to that detailed explanation, I couldn't find a comprehensive explanation. Cheers.